# Passing by reference ruining everything :(

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, parameter-passing, minimax

Hey people i have this structure for the search tree

```
class State
{
    //CLASS STATE
    int value;
    char[][] state; //the game Grid 
    State child[]; // children of current state, maximum is 8
    State(char[][] src)
    {
        state=src;
        child=new State[8];
    }
```

this is the root node definition

```
 State rootNode = new State(currentGrid);
 rootNode.value=-1;
 int v =maxValue(rootNode,depth);
```

after the end of recursion in the max value function the array in rootNode should not be edited since its the  the first state but when i Display it i get an array filled with stuff which means that the rootNode.state passed by reference to the max value function :(

//i am trying to implement MiniMax Algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want objects that are passed as parameters to be changed, pass in a copy (or make a copy of the parameter inside the method).

Note that `char[][]` means you have an array of char arrays, i.e. you are working with objects and if you copy the first level you still might have a reference to the second.

Thus you might have to loop through the first level/dimension and copy all the arrays in there, like this:

```
char target[][] = new char[state.length][0];

for( int i = 0; i < state.length; ++i ) { 
  target[i] = Arrays.copyOf(state[i], state[i].length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need, you can easily create a copy of the array through [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29)

You can also create a deep copy. How to do this has been answered here: [How to deep copy an irregular 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419858/how-to-deep-copy-an-irregular-2d-array)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java passes references to arrays and not the array as a value. So if you give a reference to your internal state away, the receiver can change it and the change is "visible" in the source (in fact: it's only *one* array that has been changed and all reference holders will see the change).

Quick fix/solution: clone your state array and pass a reference to this clone instead of the original. This will keep your internal root state unmodified.

Comment: @aioobe - cloning will do whatever you do in your cloneing algorithm (and, BTW - a shallow copy might be sufficient in his case, looks like he's just moving around objects in the array, like chess figures)