# Copy an arbitrary n-dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, deep-copy

I am basically looking for a general function copy(array) that will return identical n-dimensional array without any references to the former one.

Comment: none... but don't judge me, i am beginner in javascript. i've only looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419858/how-to-deep-copy-an-irregular-2d-array, and it wasn't general enough for my case.

Comment: @Ognjen - Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: btw i am porting some code from java to js, if you wonder why i needed this :)

Comment: Do you have to have an arbitrary copy of any types?  If you know the types and dimensions of the array, the problem is a lot easier.

Comment: Um, what do you mean by "deep copy"? Can you do it like this: `var new_array = old_array;`

Comment: @Ognjen: That linked question is on Java, not on JavaScript. Search for "javascript object copy clone"

Comment: @Derek, they want a real copy, not a reference.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I see `deep copy` many times, but I still don't get what is the difference between those two... Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Nevermind, found [this](http://blog.imaginea.com/deep-copy-in-javascript/).

Comment: @Derek - A shallow copy makes a copy of the top level items, but if there are any items deeper than that (e.g. arrays in arrays or arrays in a property), it does not make a copy of those (they end up being references to the same objects).  A deep copy makes sure that every item at every level is a copy.  A deep copy usually uses recursion.

Comment: @Derek: sorry, i accidentally pasted the wrong link! btw. thanks for the quick answers!

Answer (score 5):

This works for arrays, it won't work for nested objects (that aren't Arrays):

```
function copy(arr){
    var new_arr = arr.slice(0);
    for(var i = new_arr.length; i--;)
        if(new_arr[i] instanceof Array)
            new_arr[i] = copy(new_arr[i]);
    return new_arr;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var arr = [
   [[1,2,3],[75]], 100,
   [[[1]]], [],
   [1,[2,[3],4],5], 6, 7, 8
];

var new_arr = copy(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery (works for arrays and "plain" objects):

```
var a = [[1,[2,3]],[4]];
var b = $.extend(true, [], a);
a[0][0] = 42;             // modify object in a
alert(JSON.stringify(b)); // [[1,[2,3]],[4]]
```

Or JSON direct (if all objects are JSON-izable):

```
var a = [[1,[2,3]],[4]];
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
a[0][0] = 42;             // modify object in a
alert(JSON.stringify(b)); // [[1,[2,3]],[4]]
```

Older versions of IE (8? 7?) will need a shim for the JSON object.

Comment: Small note: If the value is `undefined`, it would not be transformed into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to Paulpro's answer. Note that this is identical to his answer except that I changed copy(new_arr[i]) to copy(arr[i]), and new_arr.length to arr.length.

```
function copy(arr){
var new_arr = arr.slice(0);
for(var i = arr.length; i--;)
    if(new_arr[i] instanceof Array)
        new_arr[i] = copy(arr[i]);
return new_arr;
}
```

The reason copy(new_arr[i]) worked is because the .slice copied over what arr[i] was pointing at, making them equal.

Also, while Paulpro's answer works for all cases, if by chance each member of each dimension of the multi-dimensional array is either an array or a non-array you can make it more efficient by only slicing non-array dimensions.
I mean what is the point of copying over an array of pointers that will simply be overwritten by the following recursion?

```
function copy(arr){
if(arr[0] instanceof Array){
    var new_arr = new Array(arr.length);
    for(var i = arr.length; i--;)
        new_arr[i] = copy(arr[i]);
}
else{var new_arr = arr.slice(0);}
return new_arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to clone a multidimensional array; Actually i had to invent `Array.prototype.clone()` in order to invent a function to generate N dimension array and initialize it with a value.

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = Array.isArray(c) ? c.clone() : c, p),[])
}

function arrayND(...n){
  return n.reduceRight((p,c) => c = (new Array(c)).fill(true).map(e => Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone() : p ));
}

var arr = arrayND(...[4,4,4],8); //last argument is the initializing value
arr[0][1][3] = "eight";
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```