# Copying a 3D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

I have got a 3D array and I want to make another copy of it into another array.

Assigning directly would return a string to the new array not a 3D array.

```
foo = [] //3D array; 
boo = foo //boo becomes a string
```

Any idea of how to do this?

Edit: 
this is the code

**Background.js**

```
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
localStorage = request.mes; // mes is an array
}; 
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(onRequest);
```

Comment: A string to the new array? You mean a reference? To copy an array, there are various methods, including `boo = foo.slice();` (=shallow copy). If you want a deep copy, recursively loop through the array), or use `bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo));` (note: only works with JSON-serializable objects). Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10941695

Comment: i dont want the new variable to be string, i want it just the other one to be an array, i tried the slice method, but it works only with 2D arrays
@assylias well you can try it, and post your code

Comment: @RobW it didnt work ... im using it in google chrome extension though...

Comment: That doesn't matter, Chrome extensions do not define special behaviour for arrays. Include your relevant code in the question + the expectations.

Comment: When you assign an array to another variable, it definitely **does not** become a string. You must be doing something strange...

Comment: @yassine_hell Where did you get the idea to use `localStorage` for saving ARRAYS (assuming that you're using `localStorage.foo=..`, and not `localStorage=..`)? `localStorage` can only save strings. If you want to save arrays, use `localStorage.setItem('bar', JSON.stringify(foo));` to save the list, and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bar');` to retrieve the item.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use clone.Try this,

```
var a = [1,2,[3,4,[5,6]]];

Array.prototype.clone = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
//      if( this[i].constructor == this.constructor ) {
        if( this[i].clone ) {
            //recursion
            arr[i] = this[i].clone();
            break;
        }
        arr[i] = this[i];
    }
    return arr;
}

var b = a.clone()

console.log(a);
console.log(b);

b[2][0] = 'a';

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: tried that before even posting here :s ...

Comment: Is it working for you or not?

Comment: Did you get any error or whats the issue with that, since when I tried   in console it works fine.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined`

Comment: Did you try this? http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_414-copy-or-clone-javascript-array-object

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found relies on using jQuery, hopefully that won't be an issue?

```
var a1 = ['test', ['a','b',1], [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]];
console.log(a1);
var a2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, a1);
a1[0] = 'test - changed';
console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/AhKNx/

Simply setting `var a2 = a1;` simply creates a reference to the original object, resulting in `a2[0]` being changed to `test - changed`;

Look at your console (F12 in Firefox/Chrome) to see the output from my fiddle ;)

Hope that helps?

Gavin