# Changing one variable changes all others defined the same way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript code which has 4 3-dimensional arrays that are each of 500x500x220 dimension (all 220 values in the last dimension are rarely all used). Because of this large dimension, it's much faster to define one array like this and then define the four arrays from that one. The problem is that then, when I change a value in one array, it changes in the others also. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var content = new Array();
var signs = new Array();
var sens = new Array();
var props = new Array();
var ini = new Array();
for(i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        ini[i] = new Array();
        for(j = 0; j < 500; j++){
                    ini[i][j] = new Array();
        }
}
content = ini;
signs = ini;
sens = ini;
props = ini;
function f(){
        alert(signs[3][3][2]);            //Returns undefined
        content[3][3][2] = 2;
        alert(signs[3][3][2]);            //Returns 2
}
f();
</script>
```

Notice that the `f()` function is only supposed to change the `content` array but it also changes the `signs` array. Why does it do that and how do I get around it?

In case it makes a difference, I'm using HTA.

Comment: You've just set ***everything*** to be the same as `ini`, meaning all the variables point to the exact same array, so changing it one place, changes it everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941695/copy-an-arbitrary-n-dimensional-array-in-javascript) about copying nested arrays.

Your code:

```
content = ini;
signs = ini;
sens = ini;
props = ini;
```

makes the arrays to point to `ini`. That's why any reference to `content[0]`, for instance, is a reference to `signs[0]` and `ini[0]` as well.

Use:

```
function copy(arr){
    var new_arr = arr.slice(0);
    for(var i = new_arr.length; i--;)
        if(new_arr[i] instanceof Array)
            new_arr[i] = copy(new_arr[i]);
    return new_arr;
}
```

to copy the arrays:

```
content = copy(ini);
signs = copy(ini);
sens = copy(ini);
props = copy(ini);
```