# Clone List Elements in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, clone, deep-copy

I have a variable of type `List<RelationHeader>`.
Now I want to copy all the elements in this list to a new list, but I want to actually copy all the members by value (clone them). Is there a quick command to do this, or do I need to iterate over the list and copy them one at a time?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/java-how-to-clone-arraylist-but-also-clone-its-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do this manually. There's no generally accepted way of deep-copying objects in Java (`clone()` is not really used for this - see [this](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) Joshua Bloch article) and you'll have to determine *yourself* how deep you want to copy those objects.