# If I return a List in Java, is the return value a reference or the actual value?

Tags: java, collections

Pretty self explanatory: I need to modify the ArrayList that I receive, but I want the original to be unchanged.

I know this is very basic, and I'm not sure why I don't know the definitive answer. I guess better late than never though.

Comment: Actually @irreputable, it is a doohickey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have a reference to the original `ArrayList`.

You can create a *shallow* copy of the list with [`clone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone()).

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/java-how-to-clone-arraylist-but-also-clone-its-items) if you want a deep copy.

Comment: @Felix Does a shallow copy mean that modifying it will modify the original copy? That would defeat the purpose of making a copy.

Comment: Java is *not* pass by reference. It may appear so, but that's because no one really uses pass-by-reference (except some C++ programmers) and hence you people don't know what it means. References (pointer) are passed by value - that's a difference, both in theory and practice.

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss: No. Follow the link, it says: *Returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements themselves are not copied.)* So changes to the copy won't modify the original, but changes to the objects *contained* in the list will modify the original objects.

Comment: A shallow copy means that it will only create a new copy of the list (this is VERY likely what you are looking for) but it won't create a copy of the content objects in that list.

Comment: @efficiencyIsBliss, I think you need a deeper understanding of reference types in Java.  `clone()` will give you a new `ArrayList` which is completely independent of the old one, however, it will contain all the same references.  Modifying one list will not affect the other list.  However, if an object *referenced* by both lists is modified, the change of course will be visible through any reference to it.

Comment: No, the contents are just ints so a shallow copy should work fine. Thanks to everyone who answered. I'd like to accept one, but it seems that I have to wait a while. Also, could someone suggest how to make this question community wiki? I feel like this would be helpful to a lot of people (if that's what community wiki is for).

Comment: @delnan: Ok I changed it a bit. Although I would say one can use the term *pass-by-reference* in "daily programming talk" without creating confusion, I'm also someone insisting on exact definitions.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I'm sorry, I meant to tag the OP and copied your name by mistake.  Yes, I meant to be in support of your answer.

Comment: @Felix: Kling: Well, since no one actually knows what pass by reference means, we might as well hijack it and use it for the more common semantics ;) Seriously, pass by reference means you can set the caller's variables and nothign else - we shouldn't use it for anyting else. It may not matter in several cases, but it's still a wholly different thing.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in java will be a reference by default. So yes changing the returned arraylist will modify the original one.

To prevent that problem you have to create a copy of the original one. Use the .clone() method for that.

Comment: You can remove the **by default**. Java has **only** pointers (or references) on objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a modified list, but not to modify the original, you shouldn't operate on the list which you received in arguments of the method because you operate on reference. Better use something like this:

```
public void modifyList(List myList) {
    myList.add("aaa"); // original *will* be modified
    List modifiable = new ArrayList(myList);
    modifiable.add("bbb"); // original will *not* be modified - only the copy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be the same ArrayList.  If you want a copy, you'll have to copy it yourself.  Not necessarily easy if the ArrayList holds complex objects!

Answer (score 0):

I think java is pass-by-value always.

The only thing to remember is that objects are passed by passing the value of their address, or reference to them, this makes it seem as if they are passed by reference in C++ terms. Because essentially, you are passing the reference address not a copy of the object. The address is passed by value.

Thus, Java can say it is always passed by value because even when it is passing an object, it is only passing the value of its memory reference on the heap stack, not a clone/copy of the target object.

An Arraylist is an object, therefore it will be passed by value, so the value passed in will be a reference to the original Arraylist on the heap. Any modification to the Arraylist in your function, will modify the original on the heap.

I have not used the .clone(). I leave that to others to help with. Meanwhile, I will go learn about them myself.