# How to make a deep copy of Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, deep-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)

trying to make a copy of an ArrayList. The underlying object is simple containing on Strings, ints, BigDecimals, Dates and DateTime object.
How can I ensure that the modifications made to new ArrayList are not reflected in the old ArrayList?

```
Person morts = new Person("whateva");

List<Person> oldList = new ArrayList<Person>();
oldList.add(morts);
oldList.get(0).setName("Mortimer");

List<Person> newList = new ArrayList<Person>();
newList.addAll(oldList);

newList.get(0).setName("Rupert");

System.out.println("oldName : " + oldList.get(0).getName());
System.out.println("newName : " + newList.get(0).getName());
```

Cheers,
P

Comment: Java is pass by reference. So initially you have the "same" object reference in both the lists...You'll need to use the `clone()` method. AFAIK you'll have to call it on each item separately

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Cloning the objects before adding them. For example, instead of `newList.addAll(oldList);`

```
for(Person p : oldList) {
    newList.add(p.clone());
}
```

Assuming `clone` is correctly overriden in`Person`.

Comment: yes, clone is shallow copy, after the clone(),  the member in the Person object is still the same reference, so you need to override the clone method according to your needs

Comment: Without the assumption of overriding, default `clone()` is protected.

Answer (score 25):

```
public class Person{

    String s;
    Date d;
    ...

    public Person clone(){
        Person p = new Person();
        p.s = this.s.clone();
        p.d = this.d.clone();
        ...
        return p;
    }
}
```

In your executing code:

```
ArrayList<Person> clone = new ArrayList<Person>();
for(Person p : originalList)
    clone.add(p.clone());
```

Comment: @Wulf `String` isn't a primitive data type in Java

Comment: @ataulm String's are immutable in Java.  Since you cannot change them, there's no point in cloning them.

Comment: "there's no point in cloning" is different from "You can't clone"