# List.of and List.copyOf methods

Tags: java

I understand that List.of and List.copyOf create immutable clone lists of the original list, so in my understanding, the below code should print [1], [1, 2] when it actually prints [[1, 2]], [1, 2]? how does List.of take the most recent view of the initial collection, col?

```
Collection<Number> col = new HashSet<>();
col.add(1);
var list1 = List.of(col); //1
col.add(2); //2
var list2 = List.copyOf(col); //3
System.out.println(list1+", "+list2);
```

Comment: It is always helpful in such cases to examine the inferred type of `var` (hover in most IDEs) and/or replace it with an explicit type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List.of` creates a new list with the parameter**s** as elements. `List.copyOf` creates a new list with the same elements as the *single* `Collection` argument.

Pseudocode Examples (note the square brackets):

```
List.of(1,2,3) == [1,2,3]
List.copyOf([1,2,3]) == [1,2,3]
List.of([1,2,3]) == [[1,2,3]]
List.of([1,2,3], [4,5,6]) == [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

The third line is similar to what's happening in your code. `of` creates a list that has the parameters as elements. What parameters did you give it? One modifiable set. So it creates an unmodifiable list with a single element, that element being your modifiable set. Note also that `of` does not copy the set.

`copyOf` creates an unmodifiable list with the same elements as the collection that you passed in. You passed in `col`, which has the elements `1`, `2`, so it creates an unmodifiable `List` with the elements `1`, `2`.

Comment: Wonderful! thank you so much for the explanation @Sweeper. Much appreciated it.

Comment: Maybe add that the variable `list1` has the type `List<Collection<Number>>`  and that the variable `list2` has the (expected?) type `List<Number>`. That made it clearer for me.

Comment: And maybe add that there exist a confusing overload `List.of(E... elements)` meaning that if you pass an array to `of()` it actually behaves as `copyOf()`

Answer (score 3):

When you do List.of(col), you don't actually add elements into it, you add the whole hashset (as a reference), so when you add an item later into the hashset, it is displayed later.

Comment: Thank you Ecto! Much appreciated, I like the explanation that List.of is actually pointing to the reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Both will create unmodifiable lists. But with `copyOf`, subsequent changes to the underlying collection will not propagate, i.e. won't be visible through `list2` in this case.

For example, if you add

```
col.add(3);
```

you'll find the change is reflected in `list1`, but not `list2`.

You may also find this post helpful:
[Java-How can i use correctly list.copyOf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851349/java-how-can-i-use-correctly-list-copyof)

See the Java docs here for more info:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable

Also:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)