# make a copy of list

Tags: java, sorting

I need to compare data retrieved from table and a list :

```
      // first click

      // get list of data
      originalList = getValue(columnX);


      // copy
      List<String> copy1 = new ArrayList<String>(originalList );

      //sort
      Collections.sort(copy1);
      System.out.println("copy" + copy1);

    // verify
     assertEquals(copy1, originalList);  //this is OK

    //second click is done here

    // copy
    List<String> copy2 = new ArrayList<String>(originalList ); 


  // sort
  Collections.sort(copy2 );
  System.out.println("copy2" + copy2 );=>copy2 give same values as copy1!!!it should  not
```

// verify
  assertEquals(copy2, originalList); =>wrong

Comment: ? what does it mean? the copy2 i created it gives me same values as copy , and it should be other values as I have clicked a second time

Comment: In between the construction of copy and copy2, originalList doesn't change... so why *shouldnt* sorting copy and copy2 yield the same result?

Comment: the first assert is OK but if I try a second assert on copy2, this fails as copy2 gives same results as copy

Comment: assertEquals is comparing *references*, not *contents* of the ArrayLists.  See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/SimpleuseofJUnittotestArrayList.htm.  And your question is still quite unclear.

Comment: Actually, when invoked with two objects, `assertEquals` does use the `equals` method, but ArrayList's `equals` will only return `true` if both lists have the same elements on _the same order_.

Comment: You need to copy each element of the list individually ... [duplicate of this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents

Comment: I have a list of data , I click to sort it , make a copy 1 and compare then click a second time to verify the sorting ,create a copy2 then use assertEquals, the second copy is wrong

Comment: i would like that copy2 five me correct data as it is the case for copy.

Comment: Show us your `assertEquals` code

Comment: clone on original list??? i don't thin this is what I 'm lookinng for as originalList gives me a correst data

Comment: @NimChimpsky: No, because these are strings, which are immutable. There's no need to clone them.

Comment: @lola: Please show a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem. No data tables, no clicking - just taking the list, copying it, sorting etc.

Comment: @Steve, Ive updated the problem by adding second assert , in fact this is the result I have : after second click[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
copy2[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2] doesn't match first list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the first `assertEquals` succeeded because the data in `originalList` *was already sorted*. Sorting `copy1` again did not change the order, hence `equals` returns true.

The second click *did change the order* (I assume that the list is now in reverse order).
Hence the second `assertEquals` fails - `originalList` and `copy2` do contain the same elements but in different order.

Comment: Depends on what you want. The original question (now edited away) was: "how could I make safely a second copy?" The answer is: Technically you did, but your definition of "safe" seems to be different than that of Java. What is your definition?

Comment: first values:OK, copy1 is OK after sort, second values after click is OK, copy2after sort is equal to copy 1???

Comment: For example. That would test, that still the same elements are there. Additionally you could test, if the second click did revert the order: Compare also to `Collections.revert(copy1); assertEquals(originalList, copy1)`