# String permutations using recursion in Java

Tags: java, string, recursion, permutation, anagram

I came across [THIS](http://learnprogramming.machinesentience.com/java_permutations_recursion/) post which tried very hard to explain the recursive solution to print all string.

```java
public class Main {
    private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
        int n = str.length();
        if (n == 0)
            System.out.println(prefix);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i),
                        str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        permutation("", "ABCD");
    }
}
```

But still I am not able to get the part when we start popping off the stack. For example, recursion goes all the way till `permutation("ABCD","")`, where base case meets and it prints `ABCD`. But what happens now? We pop off `permutation("ABC","D")` from function call stack. What we do with this and so on?

Can someone please help explain a bit?

Also, I need some pointers on the time complexity of this. Not like complete calculation but some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier example: `permutation("", "ABC")`, representing empty string as `*`:

```
* ABC + A BC + AB C - ABC *
      |      |
      |      ` AC B - ACB *
      |
      + B AC + BA C - BAC *
      |      |
      |      ` BC A - BCA *
      |
      ` C AB + CA B - CAB *
             |
             ` CB A - CBA *
```

Note that this looks like a tree laid on its side. Indeed, it called a tree. When we start, we will enter `("A", "BC")` state; we proceed to call `("AB", "C")`, and finally `("ABC", "")`. Here we print our output. Then we remember we have unfinished business, we return to a loop, but the loop in the previous level only had one cycle. So we're done there as well, and return back to `("A", "BC")` level; there are two elements in `"BC"` and we've only done the `"B"`, so it's now `"C"`'s turn: we call `("AC", "B")`, which then calls `("ACB", "")`. Now all the loops under `("A", "BC")` are done... But wait, still work to do! Because `("", "ABC")` still has two more letters to process. And so it goes, branch by branch, in what we usually call "depth-first search".

In each level is a loop. The loop shrinks (we iterate 3 times in the thick branch at the left, then 2 in the next level, then only one) but still there is a loop. So in total, we do `n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * ... * 2 * 1` iterations. `O(N!)`?

Answer (score 1):

As a kind of *recursion*, you can use [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method. First prepare a *list* of possible combinations of characters for each *character-position*, and then consecutively *reduce* the stream of these lists to a single list, by summing the pairs of list elements.

As a list element, you can use `Map<Integer,String>`, where *key* - the position of the character in the string, *value* - the character itself, and summ the contents of these maps, excluding those *keys* that are already present.

And you get a list of permutations of characters.

For example, if you have a four-character string , then you have to pass through three steps of *reduction*, consecutively accumulating the results:

| str1 + str2 = sum1 | sum1 + str3 = sum2 | sum2 + str4 = total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ``` + = + = + = ``` | ``` + = + = + = + = + = + = ``` | ``` + = + = + = + = + = + = ``` |

`15` sums for each of the `4` characters are `60` sums, resulting in `4! = 24` permutations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVXNbtpAEL7zFCOkSusKnMKRJEhRVKlVG7VSeotyWMwAa9Zea3cdRCPeom1Ofce@AZ21jTGxAStIFmbZ@eabb/5C/sT74XS53YooUdpCSAd@aoX03192amfGauSRf6ukxMAqbY7f@Rzb@@ztstNJ0okUAQSSGwN3XMTw3AH6FOfGcktfT0pMIaJ/GRmKeP7wCFzPjVdcdp@LC1BazEXMJVm5S@VfuY07hWvo/vv78oue3/T8oeele1nF4FrzNagZBAuueWBRG/fLLvA1qogt0QjUFL8rejeETTf8/QHzfKtuHB7zDnwEKrboLArgzOee7dpYjHyVWj8hh1bGLAMxhJZHwvY@PEKuQkthrINNUEep007F5jCa8vZXunp1x5MrSgfOUfcKncbjQ@trKPPlax7PkX3oVcL2JcZzu/BK3Aqb3Oqq5mnnaFwz8iOe/FDfJiET0B@/0XOFgcZEoyGxAXmw2MsA3FVbjdFRqD2v0PEiU1/NWNiD2x1iU3YewkfPO8kvyNsFeJk5cmSO0yjus32bkV@nL2tyRA6IBiUTp4JbBKqpJLV10RPEJdvX3WhUFF4josZpGlDRQt7NjrPjbsAqd0gKSMxO6n5yU8bcv4NedmnoOT2zg2I8sJOCmTSKssLMqpyLvD2daDDTKgK7Ujmd4xrOJLeUQEZGg53z4XnnFRIzIV0NkVTUv8ogLHFN8S84JVKTNJKgpmsoSu8sop/jOUJDR8h9@wR5j5TW9sRKuFjFeMdtsMhCHI3cvKHZab7g2msVX0jVC8RcC8yHFIl6si6rbVKGEeOKhky8xOknbhZNk4bRAH9uFReV7Y2UWTyVWdrOYtjCYrNp16fUFueq/O29enRO1jtJ6Y/SIHMWbhAV84jGI1WL93opxGk0ceV6uBZOLZzqPd@In8iOY2q1MsBm3EUoaPnSUb4pIZ/P0IeBV92auUV9rQxaDfdyiPAeTLLhweE9ve0kGbwiSllIo7i/EqY2/xq2i6PmvWErNQnWOdfv2SoJ4V0hyDUIr8UCqroajeZoTxu5DiiGyn5FeaRiIjnJ2IVuD7rdU2wb6tgNCIdD1k217M8oGbRvG3dK3oybzma7/Q8)

```java
// original string
String str = "";
// array of characters of the string
int[] codePoints = str.codePoints().toArray();
// contents of the array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(codePoints));
//[120276, 120277, 120278, 120279]
```

```java
// list of permutations of characters
List<Map<Integer, String>> permutations = IntStream.range(0, codePoints.length)
        // Stream<List<Map<Integer,String>>>
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, codePoints.length)
                // represent each character as Map<Integer,String>
                .mapToObj(j -> Map.of(j, Character.toString(codePoints[j])))
                // collect a list of maps
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // intermediate output
        //[{0=}, {1=}, {2=}, {3=}]
        //[{0=}, {1=}, {2=}, {3=}]
        //[{0=}, {1=}, {2=}, {3=}]
        //[{0=}, {1=}, {2=}, {3=}]
        .peek(System.out::println)
        // reduce a stream of lists to a single list
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // summation of pairs of maps from two lists
                .flatMap(map1 -> list2.stream()
                        // filter out those keys that are already present
                        .filter(map2 -> map2.keySet().stream()
                                .noneMatch(map1::containsKey))
                        // join entries of two maps
                        .map(map2 -> new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>() {{
                            putAll(map1);
                            putAll(map2);
                        }}))
                // collect into a single list
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // List<Map<Integer,String>>
        .orElse(List.of(Map.of(0, str)));
```

```java
// number of permutations
System.out.println(permutations.size()); // 24

// number of rows (factorial of string length - 1)
int rows = IntStream.range(1, codePoints.length)
        .reduce((a, b) -> a * b).orElse(1);

// column-wise output
IntStream.range(0, rows)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, permutations.size())
                .filter(j -> j % rows == i)
                .mapToObj(permutations::get)
                .map(map -> map.toString().replace(" ", ""))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
//{0=,1=,2=,3=} {1=,0=,2=,3=} {2=,0=,1=,3=} {3=,0=,1=,2=}
//{0=,1=,3=,2=} {1=,0=,3=,2=} {2=,0=,3=,1=} {3=,0=,2=,1=}
//{0=,2=,1=,3=} {1=,2=,0=,3=} {2=,1=,0=,3=} {3=,1=,0=,2=}
//{0=,2=,3=,1=} {1=,2=,3=,0=} {2=,1=,3=,0=} {3=,1=,2=,0=}
//{0=,3=,1=,2=} {1=,3=,0=,2=} {2=,3=,0=,1=} {3=,2=,0=,1=}
//{0=,3=,2=,1=} {1=,3=,2=,0=} {2=,3=,1=,0=} {3=,2=,1=,0=}
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do you check if a word has an anagram that is a palindrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67082201/15613375)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an array of permutations of the string using `map` and `reduce` methods.

This solution assumes that the original string does not contain duplicate characters, otherwise the *permutation maps* `Map<Integer,String>` should be used instead of the *permutation arrays* `String[]`.

The `reduce` method takes a pair of *permutation arrays* and sums their elements *in pairs*, accumulating the results. For example, four steps of reduction for a five-character string :

```
0 [, , , , ]
1 [, , , , ]
---
sum1: [, , , , ...]
2 [, , , , ]
---
sum2: [, , , ...]
3 [, , , , ]
---
sum3: [, , ...]
4 [, , , , ]
---
total: [, , ...]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVXNattAEL77KaaGgtQkspOjQwol5NBD2kJ6CzmspbW9irQrdkcxpuQ1eiv07wH7Bu7MSralSrZDBYvs2Z1vvp2fT6l4Emdp8rheq7wwFiElQ1SiyqI3l4OOzaGVIuetQVFOMxVDnAnn4FYoDV8GQE9tdyiQXk9GJZDTbnCHVun5/QMIO3dhfZif0QiMVXOlRUZefGi7VfmwFa5g@Ofb1@@0ftD6SesXrd/DyyaOsFaswMwgXggrYpTW8T9cyH@RlUaiEptEfjL02xE@nYh2hiCM0LxjvCCk27YZkWshbV7yHY1m5/ca76rcWKHnMhifNsCjTOo5LsItSoMy7ROSTJRACabEosTTHf2zwjjFMTquUSHlY6Dg7C3crRzKPCLnqCB2SNYTGMIw7A1YWFkIK0HoXbooilPTTLZvNTMWpIgXL6KTi@Kz@ThNK0o@ca5ul2CXiXB37noDOpmgqdLa5XuktsLVdXV7PbdV3FRuMtFyGb68FoeTtKcu5NRXmUwHdWYSKSkPFSc@HfYzsjIpY6oVVJlkGp6PAzRsJW8i5E1dJpVzwPDn/h4XYbc2vHkw767Mc39XnwOhqpGq0w4za3LApalp7S/DLBN4K4qAHM97WVzsZ9FgM1MZ1YiLQ1NtnGx2Ay4Egm/tjECTFbe6kxqP4kYVKnO7YG6vmCRpgUYSLufN4YvYkUtMvaO5fzgpx5qzOT3b6D5DJ3Akqo@WZTJGbtujzfA/42BIN@1SOa8VMi9wta/TjL3JnAwIaSOQ44emavrCsb5XQ7VT0@58DD@U@ZQrPGvN2YQE7aRl2Yhq6wOgt87WLF1T7b2BhLoHAkZwPm7BtGRwuuJMl3lj2HvUnuHDiCTzhhSzX5fpdp3U9SD1XXJwrHVTDpjC6/qaV6AO@Gw12Hs1492nDwf86oYLrqu3sS5KSdZZwvznJqyL8Tx4Xq//Ag)

```java
// original string
String str = "";
// array of characters of the string
int[] codePoints = str.codePoints().toArray();
```

```java
String[] permutations = IntStream.range(0, codePoints.length)
        // intermediate output, character-position
        .peek(i -> System.out.print(i + " "))
        // prepare an array of possible permutations for each character-position
        .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(codePoints).mapToObj(Character::toString)
                // array of characters as strings
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        // intermediate output, array of possible permutations
        .peek(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr)))
        // reduce a stream of arrays to a single array
        .reduce((arr1, arr2) -> Arrays.stream(arr1)
                // summation of pairs of strings from two arrays
                .flatMap(str1 -> Arrays.stream(arr2)
                        // filter out those characters that are already present
                        .filter(str2 -> !str1.contains(str2))
                        // concatenate two strings
                        .map(str2 -> str1 + str2))
                // collect into a single array
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        // otherwise an empty array
        .orElse(new String[0]);
```

```java
// final output
System.out.println("Number of permutations: " + permutations.length);
// number of rows
int rows = permutations.length / 10;
// permutations by columns
IntStream.range(0, rows).forEach(i -> System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, permutations.length)
                .filter(j -> j % rows == i)
                .mapToObj(j -> permutations[j])
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))));
```

Intermediate output, arrays of possible permutations for each character-position:

```
0 [, , , , ]
1 [, , , , ]
2 [, , , , ]
3 [, , , , ]
4 [, , , , ]
```

Final output, permutations by columns:

```
Number of permutations: 120
```