# How do I go through every single anagram of name's initials using recursion without using any type of loop?

Tags: java, recursion, anagram

Here's what I got so far...

I want it to be like if the initials were ABC:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

... but I can't seem to make it happen.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Anagram {

    public static String swap(String n) {
        int count = n.length();
        char[] temp = n.toCharArray();
        int in_pos = 0;
        
        if(counter(count) == 1) {
            return "Thank you!";
        }else {
            counter(count);
            String s = String.valueOf(temp);
            return swap(s);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static int counter(int c) {
        
        if(c == 0) {
            return 1;
        }else {
            return c*counter(c-1);
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Full Name: ");
        String name_full = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the initials of your full name: ");
        String name_initials = in.nextLine();
        String rep_space = name_initials.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        
        System.out.println(swap(rep_space));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer makes the assumption that the letters in the string are unique. Modifications would be required to prevent repeated anagrams otherwise.

One way to write an anagram function is to loop over each character `c`, recursively calculating the anagrams for the other letters, and appending the sub-anagrams to each `c`. The base case is when the string is only one character.

For example, here's a Java implementation:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Anagrams {
    public static List<String> anagrams(String s) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return output;
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            output.add(s);
            return output;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            String c = s.substring(i, i + 1);
            // Remove char c from string s to form string s2
            String s2 = s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1);
            // Calculate anagrams of s2 and append each to char c
            List<String> anagrams2 = anagrams(s2);
            for (String anagram : anagrams2) {
                output.add(c + anagram);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = anagrams("abc");
        for (String s : l) {
            System.out.println(s);  // abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba
        }
    }
}
```

However, as is, that approach doesn't satisfy the constraint to not use any loops. The solution can be adapted to replace the `for` loops with functions that recursively increment an index, with the base case being when the index goes out-of-bounds.

For example, here's a Java implementation, followed by details on converting `for` loops to corresponding recursive functions.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Anagrams {
    public static List<String> anagrams(String s) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (s.length() == 0)
            return output;
        if (s.length() == 1) {
            output.add(s);
            return output;
        }
        // Recursively iterate over characters
        class CharIter {
            public void run(int char_idx) {
                if (char_idx >= s.length())
                    return;
                String c = s.substring(char_idx, char_idx + 1);
                // Remove char c from string s to form string s2
                String s2 = s.substring(0, char_idx) + s.substring(char_idx + 1);
                // Calculate anagrams of s2 and append each to char c
                List<String> anagrams2 = anagrams(s2);
                // Recursively iterate over sub-anagrams
                class AnagramIter {
                    public void run(int anagram_idx) {
                        if (anagram_idx >= anagrams2.size())
                            return;
                        output.add(c + anagrams2.get(anagram_idx));
                        run(anagram_idx + 1);
                    }
                }
                new AnagramIter().run(0);
                run(char_idx + 1);
            }
        }
        new CharIter().run(0);
        return output;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = anagrams("abc");
        for (String s : l) {
            System.out.println(s);  // abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba
        }
    }
}
```

#### Converting Loops to Recursive Functions

For each converted loop, the condition for ending the loop was used as the base case of the recursive function, and the body of the loop was used as the body of the recursive function. To convey the idea, the example below shows how both a `for` loop and a recursive function can be used to print the integers between `0` and `3`.

```java
public class Loop {
    private static int NUM_LOOPS = 4;
    
    // Iterative looping
    private static void loop_iter() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LOOPS; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    
    // Recursive looping
    private static void loop_rec(int i) {
        if (i >= NUM_LOOPS)
            return;
        System.out.println(i);
        loop_rec(i + 1);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loop_iter();  // Outputs 0, 1, 2, 3
        System.out.println();
        loop_rec(0);  // Outputs 0, 1, 2, 3
    }
}
```

Because function calls require additional stack memory, the recursive approach would use more stack memory than the iterative approach. Some languages (e.g., Scheme) utilize tail call optimization so that recursive tail calls do not use any additional stack space, but this is not the case for Java.

Answer (score 1):

*Without using any type of loop*, you can use `map` and `reduce` methods as a kind of recursion:

```java
List<String> list = List.of("A", "B", "C");
List<List<String>> permutations = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        // intermediate output, element position
        .peek(i -> System.out.print(i + " "))
        // prepare a list of possible permutations for each element position
        .mapToObj(i -> list.stream().map(Collections::singletonList)
                // Stream<List<List<String>>>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // intermediate output, list of possible permutations
        .peek(System.out::println)
        // reduce a stream of 2d lists to a single 2d list
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // summation of pairs of inner lists
                .flatMap(inner1 -> list2.stream()
                        // filter out those elements that are already present
                        .filter(inner2 -> !inner1.containsAll(inner2))
                        // merge two inner lists into one
                        .map(inner2 -> Stream.of(inner1, inner2)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                // collect into a single 2d list
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // otherwise an empty list
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList());

// final output
System.out.println("Number of permutations: " + permutations.size());
permutations.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Intermediate output:

```
0 [[A], [B], [C]]
1 [[A], [B], [C]]
2 [[A], [B], [C]]
```

Final output:

```
Number of permutations: 6
[A, B, C]
[A, C, B]
[B, A, C]
[B, C, A]
[C, A, B]
[C, B, A]
```

---

<sup>See also: [String permutations using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67251741/15675591)</sup>