# Outputting permutations of ArrayList using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, permutation

I am trying to permutate the items in an ArrayList. I'm not getting the right output. I don't know what the issue is, I believe it's in the 'else' loop in the allPermutations method. The list adds all strings until the input is `-1`. Sorry if this is a typical question, I tried looking on here before asking but couldn't find any help for myself.

Here is my code:

```java
public static void allPermutations(ArrayList<String> permList,
                                   ArrayList<String> nameList) {
    // base case
    // nameList is empty after performing all permutations
    if (nameList.size() == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < permList.size(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < permList.size(); ++j) {
                System.out.print(permList.get(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); ++i) {
            ArrayList<String> tempPerm = new ArrayList<>(permList);
            String name = nameList.get(i);

            // remove from nameList and add to new perm
            nameList.remove(i);
            tempPerm.add(name);

            allPermutations(tempPerm, nameList);
        }
    }
}
```

The input is:

```
Julia Lucas Mia -1
```

The output is supposed to be:

```
Julia Lucas Mia 
Julia Mia Lucas 
Lucas Julia Mia 
Lucas Mia Julia 
Mia Julia Lucas 
Mia Lucas Julia
```

But mine is:

```
Julia Julia Julia 
Lucas Lucas Lucas 
Mia Mia Mia
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) method as a kind of *recursion*. This solution assumes that the original array may contain duplicates, and it also works if there are none.

```java
String[] strings = {"Julia", "Lucas", "Mia"};

IntStream.range(0, strings.length)
        // represent a 1d array 'n' as a 2d matrix 'n×n'
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, strings.length)
                // represent each string as Map<Integer,String>
                .mapToObj(j -> Map.of(j, strings[j]))
                // Stream<List<Map<Integer,String>>>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // intermediate output
        .peek(System.out::println)
        // reduce a stream of lists to a single list
        .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                // summation of pairs of maps from two lists
                .flatMap(map1 -> list2.stream()
                        // filter out those keys that are already present
                        .filter(map2 -> map2.keySet().stream()
                                .noneMatch(map1::containsKey))
                        // join entries of two maps
                        .map(map2 -> {
                            Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                            map.putAll(map1);
                            map.putAll(map2);
                            return map;
                        }))
                // collect into a single list
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        // List<Map<Integer,String>>
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        // final output
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Intermediate output:

```
[{0=Julia}, {1=Lucas}, {2=Mia}]
[{0=Julia}, {1=Lucas}, {2=Mia}]
[{0=Julia}, {1=Lucas}, {2=Mia}]
```

Final output:

```
{0=Julia, 1=Lucas, 2=Mia}
{0=Julia, 2=Mia, 1=Lucas}
{1=Lucas, 0=Julia, 2=Mia}
{1=Lucas, 2=Mia, 0=Julia}
{2=Mia, 0=Julia, 1=Lucas}
{2=Mia, 1=Lucas, 0=Julia}
```

---

<sup>See also: [String permutations using recursion in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67114390/15675591)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just another option if your looking at permutations, it might be better to use a library. Guava has a function for this [Collections2#permutations](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#permutations-java.util.Collection-) and you can look at the implementation [here](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#line.558).