# Generate all permutations of ArrayList<String> of a given length

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to create an algorithm where the method takes in an ArrayList and the length of the output is specified. The job of the method is to print all possible permutations of the items os the specified arraylist. For eg, if arraylist is 1,2 and length given is 3, it should give output as
112,122,121,212

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating all possible permutations of a list recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305153/generating-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list-recursively)

Answer (score 2):

The resultant can be built by recursively adding all the possible characters to an existing result until you get to the wished length. You start with an empty result.
The algorithm for this is pretty easy:

```
public static void main(String... arg) {
    int n = 2;
    int l = 3;

    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a.add(Integer.toString(i+1));
    }
    perm(a, "", l);
}

private static void perm(List<String> a, String result, int l) {
    if (result.length() == l) {
        System.out.println(result);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        String nr = result + a.get(i);
        perm(a, nr,l );
    }
}
```

output:

```
111
112
121
122
211
212
221
222
```

Comment: how would I be able to get the result as {1,1,1},{1,1,2}etc.

Comment: @S.Else you mean a list of lists?

Comment: I'd actually like to give out a list every time

Comment: @S.Else instead of  System.out.println(result); you can push the result in a list that it is a field of the class. Instead of String nr = result + a.get(i); create a new list from the previous list and add the token at the end of it.

Comment: just for clarification, if (result.length() == l) happens more than just one time, correct???

Comment: @S.Else yes, each one is a different "permutation".

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry for bothering you again but do you know how i could limit the no. of different entries. For eg: input maybe 1,2,3 but i only want result as combination of 1 and 2 or 2 and 3 or 1 and 3

Comment: @S.Else this is a different question. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider by clicking the check-mark. for your new question; you can check when adding to the list/printing if it matches your conditions.

Comment: Sorry, to have to unselect your answer but it causing stackoverflow error

Comment: @S.Else If you work with large sets i'm pretty sure it does