# How can i find all combination subset for N columns?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Assume that I have a table with N columns. And I need a subset for all combinations of columns. For example, If there are C1,C2,.....,Cn columns, I need

```
1D = {C1,C2,C3,C4,.....,Cn}
2D = {C1C2,C2C3,C1C3,.....,Cn-1Cn} // 2D is all combination set for 2 columns.
3D = {C1C2C3,C1C2C4,C1C2C5,......}
```

...

I will use `Vector<Vector<String>>` setofNDSubset. (java) 
I think it will be Vector(1D,2D,3D,......,ND).
And I use jdbc. 
Column number should be less than 10.

I need some advices for you. Thanks.

Comment: is this about the appropriate SQL-query, or do you want to construct the set in java? In either way be prepared that the output-size will explode.

Comment: What's the background for this question?

Comment: I want to construct the set in java.

Comment: Column number should be less than 10, so i think it won't be explode.

Comment: If you're not interested in subsets smaller than `N` then search for permutations generation algorithm. For example: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305153/generating-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list-recursively)