# Create a Set of lists from two lists through recursion

Tags: java, recursion, set

I've searched through many questions on this site with somewhat *similar underlying concepts*, however after **many hours** of attempting to solve this problem myself and reviewing I am still lost. If there is another question that answers this I will be more than happy to give it a look over.

Ultimately I want to create a **recursive method** such that it takes two lists and returns a **Set of String lists**:

```
//Example of such a function definition
private static Set<List<String>> myRecursiveMethod(List<String> listOne, 
List<String> listTwo) {
}
```

When I say "Set of String lists" I mean **specifically** the following:
(Note:"AD" == "DA")

```
// if the two following lists are INPUTTED into myRecursiveMethod();
// listOne = ["A","B"]
// listTwo = ["C","D"]
// the following set is OUTPUTTED: [["AC","BD"],["AD","BC"]]
```

Such that if there were three elements in both listOne and listTwo, there would be SIX elements in the set. i.e:

```
// listOne = ["A","B","C"]
// listTwo = ["D","E","F"]
// OUTPUTTED: [["AD","BE","CF"],["AD","BF","CE"],["BD","AE","CF"],
// ["BD","AF","CE"],["CD","AE","BF"],["CD","AF","BE"]]
```

I tried writing this using a double enhanced FOR loop so I could understand the logic. My FOR loop approach is terrible and **only** works for the HARD-CODED limit of list.size() == 2.

```
// Create Lists and append elements 
List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
listOne.add("A");
listOne.add("B");

List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
listTwo.add("C");
listTwo.add("D");

// List One = ["A","B"]
// List Two = ["C","D"]

// Create new List
List<List<String>> newList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
Integer counter = 0;

    for (String s : listOne) {
        counter++;
        for (String p : listTwo) {

            // A HARD-CODED bad implementation of this method
            if (counter < 3) {
                List<String> newListTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
                newListTwo.add(s.concat(p));
                newList.add(newListTwo);

            } else if (!(counter % 2 == 0)) {
                newList.get(1).add(s.concat(p));

            } else {
                newList.get(0).add(s.concat(p));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newList); // = [["AC","BD"],["AD","BC"]]
```

Also you can note that I defined List<List<String>> **Rather than** Set<List<String>>. This was due to my badly coded attempted which relies on the list.get() method.

So my current recursive method is as follows:

```
private static Set<List<String>> myRecursiveMethod(List<String> listOne, 
List<String> listTwo) 
{
    //Base Case:
    if (listOne.isEmpty){
        return new HashSet<List<String>>;
    }
    //Recursive Case:
    else {
        String listOneFirst = listOne.get(0);
        String listTwoFirst = listTwo.get(0);

        List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sampleList.add(listOneFirst+listTwoFirst);

        Set<List<String>> newSet = new HashSet<List<String>>(myRecursiveMethod())
        newSet.add(sampleList);
        return newSet;
    }
}
```

This method only acts like this currently:

INPUT:

- List One = ["A","B"]
- List Two = ["C","D"]

OUTPUT:

- [["AC"]["BD"]]

DESIRED OUTPUT:

- [["AC","BD"],["AD","BC"]]

**EDIT:**

After reviewing responses my W.I.P code for the class:

```
private static Set<List<String>> myRecursiveMethod(List<String> listOne,
        List<String> listTwo) {

    //Backup Case (user enters an empty list)
    if (listOne.isEmpty()){
        return new HashSet<List<String>>();
    }

    // Base Case:
    if (listOne.size() == 1) {
        List<String> mergedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : listTwo) {
            mergedStrings.add(listOne.get(0).concat(s));
        }
        Set<List<String>> builtHashSet = new HashSet<List<String>();
        builtHashSet.add(mergedStrings);
        return builtHashSet;
    }
    // Recursive Case:
    else {

        // Ensure original list values arn't changed.
        List<String> newListOne = new ArrayList<String>(listOne);
        List<String> newListTwo = new ArrayList<String>(listTwo);

        //first two elements...I don't think this is correct
        String listOneFirst = newListOne.get(0);
        String listTwoFirst = newListTwo.get(0);
        List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sampleList.add(listOneFirst + listTwoFirst);

        //used for making recursive case smaller
        newListOne.remove(0);

        // Calls recursion
        Set<List<String>> newSet = new HashSet<List<String>>(
                myRecursiveMethod(newListOne, newListTwo));
        newSet.add(sampleList);

        return newSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to understand that detail: this is homework, and you are **asked** to create a recursive method? As I think a non-recursive method should be straight forward ...

Comment: It's not **directly** coursework. I am using this to further my knowledge in recursion and I've based the method off of a **similar question** I was asked previously but was never able to solve.

Comment: I do not really see the need for recursion here, as there is always a fixed number of input parameters (2). If I understand the rules for producing the strings correctly, there are two steps: find all permutations of the second list's items, then concat them with the elements from the first list. Iteration is perfectly fine here; and if you split it up into two steps you should be able to untangle it and make easily make it independant of the lists' length.

Comment: Maybe this can help you in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10305419/7653073.  It is a recursive approach to generating the permutations of a list.

Comment: In a **real life** application I would most definitely approach this with Iteration as it is what makes the most sense to me. However I would like to learn from what I could not previously solve and hence. 
@MalteHartwig Thanks for the link I will give it a look over now.

Comment: @Capta4437 Yes, I see now that the permutation part of your problem is actually a good example for recursion, guess I did not think it through enough at first. Good luck with it!

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (listOne.isEmpty){
    return new HashSet<List<String>>;
}
```

You are correct, at some point your recursion has to **end**, and you have to start *building* the desired output. But the desired output is **not** a Set with an empty list. It is a Set containing some lists with some content. Thus: don't wait until listOne is empty. Instead:

```
if (listOne.size() == 1) {
  List<String> mergedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
  mergedStrings = ... merge the ONE listOne entry with all listTwo entries
  Set<List<String>> rv = new HashSet<>();
  rv.add(mergedStrings);
  return rv;
}
```

In other words: you use recursion to reduce the length of the first list by one. And when only *one* element is left in that list, it is time to merge in the second list.

Now lets look into how to "use" that (calling the method rec for brevity); putting down some pseudo code to show the steps we need:

```
rec([a, b], [c,d]) -->
rec([a], [c,d]) X rec([b], [c, d]) -->
<[ac, ad]> X <[bc, bd]> -->
<[ac, ad], [bc, bd]>
```

"X" meaning "joining" two results from recursive calls; should be as easy as:

```
Set<List<String>> rec1 = rec(...);
return rec1.addAll(rec2 ...
```

Comment: I'll give this a try now, and see how I go.

Comment: Following this through my **mergedStrings** becomes a single list of all the possible listOne entry + listTwo entries:
`for (String s : listTwo) {
    mergedStrings.add(listOne.get(0).concat(s));
   }`
However if I want any entry (i.e. A, B, C or D) to **only occur once** with a single list object I'm stuck on what I am to be recursing. I've added an update of my new Code (not sure if this is standard procedure for questions).

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat, big help, i'll go through it when I have the time :)

Comment: Oh right, I'm still new to this whole service, will do.