# Java Deep Cloning an object that contain an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, clone

Hi I have to deep clone an object that contains an array list.

```
public class Objct1 implements Cloneable {
    ArrayList<Objt> o = new ArrayList();

    public Object1() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // This should never happen
            throw new InternalError(e.toString());
        }
    }
}

public class Objt implements Cloneable {
    private int ca;

    /**
     * @return the x
     */
    public int getCa() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @param x the x to set
     */
    public void setCa(int ca) {
        this.ca = ca;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() {
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // This should never happen
            throw new InternalError(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to clone the `Objct1` in this example

```
Objct1 a = new Objct1 ();

arryOfObjct1[count] = (Objct1) a.clone();
```

Comment: you are not deep cloning, for deep cloning you have to iterate all the array list and Objt should do a deep clone to in the clone method, may be you can serialize them and desiaralize  you obtain a deep copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicated:
[How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)

The @zerocool answer is not valid because is not cloning objects contained in ArrayList.