# New ArrayList with same values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> example = new ArrayList<Integer>();
example.add(1);
example.add(1);
example.add(2);
example.add(3);
example.add(3);
```

So I want to make others three ArrayLists containing in which one the same values (where there is just one value the ArrayList would have just the one).

Is that possible?

Comment: Three passes over and it still confuses me.  Do you want a list that only has one element, or three lists that contain one distinct element each?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)

Comment: I want to group the same elements creating new ArrayLists. If I have (1,1,2) I want to create an ArrayList containing 1, 1 and other containing 2.

Comment: One thing you could do is have a `Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>`, and have each `Integer` map to its corresponding `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach to filtering out the elements, implemented:  using a generic Map (in a generic class) to encapsulate the values.

- The key is the object we want, and the value is determined as follows:

  - If the key never existed, we have a list with at most one element, which is the same as the key;
  - If the key has existed prior, we have a list with at least one element, which is the same as the key.

Here's how it's laid out.  You instantiate it with the type of object you want to split.

```
public class UniqueSplitter<T> {

    public Map<T, List<T>> filterOutElements(final List<?> theCandidateList) {
        final Map<T, List<T>> candidateMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Object element : theCandidateList) {
            if(candidateMap.containsKey(element)) {
                candidateMap.get(element).add((T) element);
            } else {
                final List<T> elementList = new ArrayList<>();
                elementList.add((T) element);
                candidateMap.put((T)element, elementList);
            }
        }
        return candidateMap;
    }
}
```