# Clarification regarding static variable behaviour in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class :

```
class Dummy{
public  static ArrayList<String> varArray;
}
```

In another class I do this :

```
Class Dummy2{

   void main()
     {
         ArrayList<String> temp = Dummy.varArray;

     }

}
```

Now suppose in `Dummy2` I add elements to `temp`. Will the changes be reflected in `Dummy.varArray`? Because this is what is happening in my program. I tried printing the address of the two and they both point to the same address. Didn't know `static` field worked like this. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not about static. The statement `ArrayList<String> temp = Dummy.varArray;` means that both variables are referring to the same arraylist. As `varArray` is static, it will have only one copy.

You can read `ArrayList<String> temp = Dummy.varArray;` as, **The variable temp is now referring to the ArrayList object which is being referred by Dummy.varArray**

By the way, you need to initialize it using `public  static ArrayList<String> varArray = new ArrayList<String>();` before you perform any operations on it.

Comment: Is this true when `varArray` is not static?

Comment: @Aneesh. If you just assign one reference to another, it won't matter whether its static or non static. They will refer to the same object. You can read sureshatta's answer for more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList<String> temp = Dummy.varArray;` will take what is known as a *reference copy* (or a *shallow copy*). That is, they will point to the same object.

It does not take a deep copy. See [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is behaving correctly.

When you do this

```
ArrayList<String> temp = Dummy.varArray;
```

Both pointing to the same reference ,since `temp` not a `new`  list, you just telling that refer to  `Dummy.varArray`

To make them independent, create a new list

```
ArrayList<String> temp =  new ArrayList<String>(); //new List
temp.addAll(Dummy.varArray); //get those value to my list
```

**Point to note:**

When you do this  `temp.addAll(Dummy.varArray)`  at that point what ever the elements in the  `varArray`  they add to `temp`.

```
 ArrayList<String> temp =  new ArrayList<String>(); //new List
 temp.addAll(Dummy.varArray); //get those value to my list
 Dummy.varArray.add("newItem");// "newitem" is not  there in temp
```

The later added elements won't magically add to `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

The static keyword means there will only be one instance of that variable and not one variable per instance.