# Why is my original arraylist amended even though I only make changes to my ArrayList within the method without changing the orignal ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BubbleSort {

  // the sort method takes in an ArrayList of Strings, sorts 
  // them in ascending number of characters, and returns a new
  // ArrayList of Strings which is already sorted. This method 
  // does NOT modify the original ArrayList passed in.

  public ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> a){
    ArrayList<String> sortingList = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortingList = a;
    String test = "";
    String test2 = "";
    int length = 0;
    int length2 = 0;
    for(int j =0; j<a.size(); j++){
        for (int i =0; i<sortingList.size()-1; i++){
            test = a.get(i);
            test2 = a.get(i+1);
            length = test.length();
            length2 = test2.length();
            if(length2<length){
                sortingList.set(i,test2);
                sortingList.set(i+1,test);
            }
        }
    }
    return sortingList;
 }
}
```

*=================================MAIN METHOD=====================================*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BubbleSortTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();

    // get inputs from user
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of Strings to enter: ");
    int no = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // clears buffer in Scanner

    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++){
      System.out.print("Enter String number " + i + ": ");
      inputs.add(sc.nextLine());  // add input into ArrayList
    }

    // invoke the sort method to see if it works
    BubbleSort bs = new BubbleSort();
    ArrayList<String> sortedInputs = bs.sort(inputs);

    // print out the Strings in sortedInputs
    System.out.println("Sorted sequence:");
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedInputs.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(sortedInputs.get(i));
    }

    // print out the Strings in the original inputs
    System.out.println("Original sequence:");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++){
      System.out.println(inputs.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

input example

121234256464534

1123123

123141243124124

123

my sorting sequence &
original sequence are both amended in ascending sequence[image] even though I created a new arraylist to return
while ensuring I did not make any changes to the original one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sortingList = a;
```

Both references, sortingList and a are pointing to the same ArrayList object

Check this question to see how to see how to clone the list: [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)

Comment: ... use `ArrayList<String> sortingList = new ArrayList<String>(a)`.

Comment: I think you're right, perhaps I am moving a little too fast ahead of my curriculum. Could you elaborate a little further? or direct any research reference I could use? @Evans

@ Axel
I tried, it didnt't work

Comment: However, i assign a new ArrayList and making sure that I do not amend it but pointing the new arraylist to the a
but my original a arraylist still got amended?
WHY!?

Comment: Here's a good explanation, around Figure 7: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from your code,

```
   ArrayList<String> sortingList = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortingList = a; //REMOVE THIS LINE
```

As you are assigning a new arraylist object just before but in the next line you are storing  the reference to original object in **sortingList** object.

If you want to copy all the elements to **sortingList** then look at [Evans Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860653/why-is-my-original-arraylist-amended-even-though-i-only-make-changes-to-my-array/19860725#19860725) but in your example you do not need it as you are assigning the **test** and **test2** variables from original Array supplied.

Answer (score 1):

As Axel pointed, use:

```
ArrayList<String> sortingList = new ArrayList<String>(a);
```

With that change, in your BubbleSort class, you are still referencing strings from "a" array, hence they are not being sorted properly. To fix, change:

```
test = a.get(i);
test2 = a.get(i+1);
```

to

```
test = sortingList.get(i);
test2 = sortingList.get(i+1);
```

Full code:

```
public ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> a){

    //As Axel pointed, use:
    ArrayList<String> sortingList = new ArrayList<String>(a);

    String test = "";
    String test2 = "";
    int length = 0;
    int length2 = 0;

    for(int j =0; j<sortingList.size(); j++){
        for (int i =0; i<sortingList.size()-1; i++){

            //reference "sortingList" array instead of "a" array
            test = sortingList.get(i);
            test2 = sortingList.get(i+1);

            length = test.length();
            length2 = test2.length();

            if(length2<length){
                sortingList.set(i,test2);
                sortingList.set(i+1,test);
            }
        }
    }
    return sortingList;
}
```