# Updating similar objects in java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Let's say I have an Object called `Index`, this object has two attributes `Long id; , String name;` and I have two `ArrayLists` in my page, the problem is that when I edit the name of the index object in the first list it is being edited in the second list as well, here is my code to make the problem more understandable:

```
Index index1 = new Index();
index1.setName("1");
index1.setId(1);

List<Index> indexes = new ArrayList<Index>();
indexes.add(index1);

List<Index> newIndexes = new ArrayList<Index>();
newIndexes.add(index1);
```

Now if I update  the name of the index in the `indexes` list it is being updated in the `newIndexes` list. note: the object index has equals method on the `Id` field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference `index1` is the same for both lists, so changing the `Index` referenced will change it in both.

Cloning the `List` per se won't fix your issue, as it'll clone the `List` but not its elements.

You need to perform a deep-clone of the `List` **and** its elements (or initialize a new `ArrayList`, as you do, and clone each of the previous `List`'s elements) to solve your issue.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents) for the how-to.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `index1` is just a reference to the object. So, your are basically adding the same reference to both of the lists. You need to copy the object before adding to the second list.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the object to both the lists, the reference of that object is copied to the lists. And that's why when you object the object from one list, it is reflected back in the other. To avoid this, you need to create a copy of the object and add it to the other list, so that both do not refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you use "Add" on array list (and in almost every data collection object) the collection is adding the "reference" of the object to its list, and not creating a new object.
Thus, when both `index1` objects at `indexes` and `newIndexes` are basically the same one. When changing it no matter where, it will be changed at the other as well.