# How to deep clone an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, clone

How can I clone an `arrayList` with the following structure:

```
List<empItem> empList = new ArrayList<empItem> ();
```

I need to create a clone in such a way that i need to modify the `empItem` without affecting the original?

Yes the same scenario has an answer already.[How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents) But since the post is Outdated , i am looking for any fresh / latest way ..

Comment: Also, [apache-commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html) might be handy

Comment: @jegadees if you can justify what is wrong with answers in that thread, maybe show examples, and clarify what you mean by latest and why you think there would've been changes, you should add that to the question. It might get reopened then. Currently the question contains no reason to think it's nothing more than a duplicate.