# Deep copy of an ArrayList<Arraylist> in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, deep-copy

I checked other answers but I could not find a proper answer to my question.
I want to create a copy of my `ArrayList<ArrayList>`, since I need the original one somewhere else. I used the `.clone()` method in different ways:

```
public class WordChecker {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList> copyOfList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

    public WordChecker(ArrayList<ArrayList> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                copyOfList = (ArrayList<ArrayList>) list.clone(); // without error
                // copyOfList = list.clone();cannot convert from Object to
                // ArrayList<ArrayList>
                // copyOfList = list.get(i).clone();cannot convert from Object to
                // ArrayList<ArrayList>
                // copyOfList = list.get(i).get(j).clone();
    }
```

but still my main `ArrayList` changes as I work on its copy.
Could anybody tell me how I should get a deep copy in this case?

**Answer:**
I put the copying mechanism in my class constructor:

```
private ArrayList<List> checkedTags = new ArrayList<List>();
public WordChecker(ArrayList<ArrayList> list)
  {
     for (ArrayList word: list) copyOfList.add((ArrayList) word.clone());

}
```

the only problem is that this is not applicable to copy from ArrayList which made me to go through a for loop use .get() method.I feel they are basically the same at the end.

Comment: Don't use clone(). Use the ArrayList constructor that takes another collection as argument. And you'll need to loop if you want a deep copy.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents

Comment: I made a nested loop to reach to every item in the inner ArrayList. it throws the error mentioned in front of the code. I used this code: >> for (ArrayList word: list) copyOfList.add(word.clone())... too.
but it cannot accept .add .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply use `ArrayList(Collection c)` constructor

```
public <T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> deepCopy(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> source) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> dest = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
    for(ArrayList<T> innerList : source) {
        dest.add(new ArrayList<T>(innerList));
    }
    return dest;
}
```

**Caution:** 
As mentioned by @Tim B this does not deep copy the elements within ArrayList

Comment: Be aware that while this will deep copy the lists it will not deep copy the items within the lists.

Comment: I did as I edited my post. I am not really good at using generic methods...:D

Comment: If it does not deep copy the elements of list then its not deep copy.

Comment: @Vatsal  I have already mentioned this in my answer.. am I missing anything else ?