# Android Deep Copy of an ArrayList

Tags: android, arrays, list, deep-copy

My ArrayList looks like this:

Parent1, Parent2, ..., Parentn

Each Parent has a ChildList

Child1, Child2, ..., Childm

Every Child holds some Strings, int etc.

How do I create a deep copy of it?

Comment: You could create an image to make this more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)