# ArrayList Deep Copy

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, deep-copy

I have the following code that creates a shallow copy of the arraylist however, I'd like to change it to create a deep copy but I'm not sure how. I have tried looking online but couldn't really find an answer.

My code now is:

```
public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1.5);
    list1.add(2.5);
    list1.add(3.5);

    ArrayList<Double> list2 = (ArrayList<Double>)list1.clone();
    ArrayList<Double> list3 = list1;

    list2.add(4.5);
    list3.remove(1.5);
   System.out.println("list1 is " + list1);
   System.out.println("list2 is " + list2);
   System.out.println("list3 is " + list3);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents

Comment: I tired that but I can't seem to get that method to work not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Why do you want a deep copy of an immutable class??? What is your code snippet supposed to demonstrate? This is working as expected and it wouldn't do anything different, even if you did a deep copy of that `ArrayList`.

Comment: I just want it to demonstrate that  one list is the deep clone of another

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons's SerializationUtils.
To use SerializationUtils, class must implement *Serializable* interface.
[Reference](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html#clone-T-)

Answer (score 0):

Deep copy would be something like this

```
ArrayList<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1.5);
    list1.add(2.5);
    list1.add(3.5);

ArrayList<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();

for (Double d : list1){
list2.add(d);
}
```