# Generic LinkedList clone in Java

Tags: java, generics

I want to clone any LinkedList, whether or not it holds things which can be primitive wrappers. I understand it can be a deep recursive call to get a true deep clone - but I want just one level of cloning. I cannot compile the following code :

```
   <T> LinkedList<T> deepCloneOneLevel (final LinkedList<T> input){
        if(input != null){
            LinkedList<T> clone = new LinkedList<>();
            for (T t: input){   
                clone.add(t.clone());  //error : clone() has protected access
            }
            return clone;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can't. Not all objects are cloneable. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: Small comment on your code: the `for` loop may be simplified to a `collect()` call using Java 8.

Comment: Even if I add a check (if t instanceof Cloneable); it doesn't work. Why is that ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: For a working example see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/715660/5717099). However, as JB Nizet said this requires all the objects inside that list to implement *cloneable*. Generally I would prefer an explicit copy constructor over using `.clone`, though. Rationale [here](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Comment: @bcsb1001: Thanks. But I am working on Android, which only support Java 7 as of now.

Comment: @SlowAndSteady The reason for that is that `Cloneable` is a marker interface and doesn't, on the code level, guarantee a `public` `clone()` method. It _should_ have this if it follows the spec, but if you look at the actual source of `Cloneable` you will find a huge Javadoc followed by an empty `interface`.

Comment: The Cloneable interface is horribly designed: it doesn't guarantee that an object has a public clone() method. Instead, it just serves as a marker for the protected Object.clone() method to not throw an exception. You'd better define your own interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Java's Cloneable is not a very friendly method to clone an object. So, You might need to define your `Cloneable` interface, and make sure

```
interface MyClone<T>{
  T clone();
}
```

And use that in your code

```
 <T extends MyClone<? super T>> LinkedList<T> deepCloneOneLevel (final LinkedList<T> input){
    if(input != null){
        LinkedList<T> clone = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T t: input){   
            clone.add(t.clone());
        }
        return clone;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And implementations of `MyClone` know if a shallow copy is enough or a deep copy is required

But what if the type doesn't implement `MyClone`? Good question. We can add an overload that takes a `clone` "factory".

```
<T> LinkedList<T> deepCloneOneLevel (final LinkedList<T> input, Function<T,T> factory){
    if(input != null){
        LinkedList<T> clone = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T t: input){   
            clone.add(factory.apply(t));
        }
        return clone;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If your platform doesn't have `Function` yet, you can easily write your own, or use Guava's one.

Comment: With this approach I might not be able to handle Integer and String types, right ?

Comment: Accepting this answer, although I cannot use this in full, as Function in not available in Android/Java7

Comment: @SlowAndSteady you can easily define your own, no?

Comment: I would use `UnaryOperator<T>` rather than `Function<T, T>` here.

Comment: I have never used Function and UnaryOperator before - guess it's time to read !

Comment: @SlowAndSteady you should really tell us what you want to achieve, at a higher level. Cloning Integer and String doesn't make any sense: they're both immutable, and cloning them only uses CPU cycles and memory for nothing.

Comment: @JBNizet My wordings were incorrect. I meant to ask what if T is in a third party library and I cannot implement MyClone easily - and Sleiman Jneidi has already answered that part.

Answer (score 1):

Since `clone()` method is a big mess in java world, one solution may be to use apache commons SerializationUtils. It uses serialization to copy objects and as a result is slow. What is worse you'll have troubles if your class contains fields that do not support serialization. Here's an example:

```
<T extends Serializable> LinkedList<T> deepCloneOneLevel (final LinkedList<T> input) {
    if (input != null) {
        LinkedList<T> clone = new LinkedList<>();
        for (T t : input){
            clone.add(SerializationUtils.clone(t));
        }
        return clone;
    }
    return null;
}
```