# java items list1 to list2

Tags: java, list, javafx

So, I have to transfer the items of my second list to my first list but it isn't working. 

Here is my code:

```
private List<Kaart> gepakt;
 public void addGepakt (Kaart kaart) {
    this.gepakt.add(kaart);
 }
```

Second list code:

```
private List<Kaart> speler1gepakt;
public List<Kaart> getSpeler1gepakt() {
    return speler1gepakt;
}

public void setSpeler1gepakt(List<Kaart> speler1gepakt) {
    this.speler1gepakt = speler1gepakt;
}
```

Adding value to second list:

```
view.getSpeler1Kaarten()[1].setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event) {
            model.setSelected(view.getSpeler1Kaarten()[1].getImage());
            view.getSpeler1Kaarten()[1].setImage(new Image("WippenGame/View/Images/BlancoKaart.png"));
            model.getSpeler1gepakt().add(model.getSpeler().getKaart(1));
        }
    });

view.getSpeler2Kaart5().setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            //items of list2 have to go into list1
        }
    });
```

and here is my problem: when you click on this image, it should transfer the items of list 2 to list 1. I have tried many solutions but none of them seems to work, anyone does have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/715660/5918614

Comment: Your code doesn't call `setSpeler1gepakt`.

Comment: If all you want it to copy the items, then just do `list1.addAll(list2)`

Comment: @LionelRenaux thx, this post really helped me to understand lists better.

Comment: @TheMightyRoy You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try either this:

```
gepackt = (List<Kaart>)speler1gepakt.clone();
```

or this:

```
gepackt = new List<Kaart>(speler1gepakt);
```

I don't have time to test it now, hope it helps!