# Editing in a copy arraylist from original one

Tags: java, pointers, arraylist

Now, I have encountered this problem:

I have a non-empty array list declared as `original`. Then I do this :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> temp = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>) original.clone();

temp.get(0).set(1,-1) ;
```

but the result was that unexpectedly the element at index `1` in both lists were changed.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Before remove: `original=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] temp=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, after remove: `original=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] temp=[[1, 2, 3]]`

Comment: I tried your code as well and it works like a charm. unless you're trying to remove an element from the inner array!

Comment: how ? actually i am doing this but it's the same like removing : temp.get(0).set(1, -1);

Comment: Have you tried using the `addAll(Collection)` method?

Comment: It's really not the same at all.  `temp.remove(1)` is changing `temp`, `temp.get(0).set(1, -1)` is changing a number in a list contained by `temp`.

Comment: Ok it's my mistake

Comment: You need to make a [deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents) of `original`.

Comment: I applaud your attempt to simplify the code for your question.  Just make sure in the future that you actually run your sample code to make sure you didn't simplify your error out of it! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clone makes a shallow copy of the `ArrayList`. Either make it's Deep Copy since the ArrayList is object type so it can also make new object of it's reference.

Comment: so what can i do to copy it  ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to deep copy, you can try below code 
    for(int element:original)
    {
        temp.add(element);
    }

Answer (score 0):

`clone` makes a shallow copy of the `ArrayList`. In a sense, this means affecting the `ArrayList` from one reference also affects the other reference.

Instead, use `new ArrayList(original)`.

**Edit:** My mistake. You'd have to go through the contents of your `ArrayList` and clone each object inside. Unfortunately for you, you have `ArrayList`s inside your `ArrayList`, so you'd have to do a lot of iterating if you want distinct `Integer`s.

Comment: unfortunately same result !

Comment: `new ArrayList(original)` is also a shallow copy.