# How do I make a deep copy of an ArrayList<Integer> in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, deep-copy

I am basically just trying to make a deep copy of ones and zeroes, so I could have used booleans, but I was wondering how to do this in genereal for integers.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> makeDeepCopyInteger(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> newA = new ArrayList<>(a.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        int newInt = 0;
        if (a.get(i) == 1) {
            newInt = 1;
        }
        newA.add(newInt);
    }
    return newA;
}
```

Comment: Since Integers are immutable, why would you want to deep copy them?

Answer (score 3):

The `clone()` method is protected by the `Integer` class, so you cannot call `Integer.clone()` outside of that class. What you can do instead is create a `new` Integer.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> makeDeepCopyInteger(ArrayList<Integer> old){
    ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<Integer>(old.size());
    for(Integer i : old){
        copy.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

You can test that this works by doing something like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        arr.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> x = makeDeepCopyInteger(arr);
    for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++){
        if(arr.get(i) == x.get(i)){
            System.out.println("Same object");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not the same object");
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Tests

```
Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = new Integer(a);

System.out.println(a==b); // true
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a) == (System.identityHashCode(b))); // false;


Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = a;

System.out.println(a==b); // true
System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(a) == (System.identityHashCode(b))); // true
```

So from my testing it seems that to create a new reference for copying to a new array, you should use `new Integer()`. `Integer` is an immutable object but that reference changes when the value of `Integer` changes.

Comment: Since `Integer` is immutable, you don't *need* to create a copy of it.

Comment: @Kayaman I did some testing on this, see my edit. Maybe I'm confused but by not creating a copy it seems to keep the old reference.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. Since the value of `Integer` can't change, it doesn't matter if you have 1000 lists all referring to the same `17` for example. Your last paragraph is erroneous. Since `Integer` is immutable, its value cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

Use streams to copy objects. Easy to read, good for JIT. Following code provides a copy of a list with Integer object copies inside.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> makeDeepCopyInteger(ArrayList<Integer> a){
    return a.stream().map(val -> new Integer(val)).collect(toList());
}
```

To copy custom objects other than Integer override implement and call clone()

```
return a.stream().map(MyObjectClass::clone).collect(toList());
```

Instead of clone you can use serialization to json. E.g. as used in BeanUtils.getCopy(sourceBean) in following [java-utils](https://github.com/azee/java-utils)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to iterate over the items of the list and clone them before, adding them to the new list, as mentioned here:

[How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like:

```
public static List<Integer> clone(List<Integer> source) {
   return source.stream()
       .map( intObj -> new Integer(intObj.intValue()))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or, more old-fashioned:

```
public static List<Integer> clone(List<Integer> source) {
   List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Integer intObj : source) {
      newList.add(new Integer(intObj.intValue()));
   }
   return newList;
}
```

Both of these could be made shorter by taking advantage of auto-boxing / auto-unboxing. But I've made it explicit to make it absolutely clear what's going on.

However, it's a pointless exercise - in fact it's actively wasteful of memory and detrimental to performance. `Integer` is immutable, so it's *better* for references to point at the same instance of `Integer`. Because it's not possible for the `Integer` to change value, it's impossible to cause any harm by sharing an instance.

This holds true for immutable objects in general, and is the reason they are a good thing.

You are very unlikely, as a beginner, to find a case in which `new Integer(...)` is a good idea (or even `Integer.valueOf(int i)`, although this one might return a cached instance). If you already have an `Integer`, use the one you have:

```
 Integer oldVar = ... ;
 Integer newVar = oldVar;
```

Immutability means that will always be OK. It is impossible for an operation on `newVar` to corrupt `oldVar` because there is no `newVar.setValue(newValue)`.

If you have an `int` use it directly and allow Java's auto-boxing to convert it into an `Integer`:

```
 int oldValue = ... ;
 Integer newValue = oldValue ; // Java will automatically put this through
                               // Integer.valueOf(int i)
```

---

You mentioned that you really wanted to work with booleans. You should consider using `BitSet`.