# ArrayList objects are overridden

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Trying to work on a genetic algorithm here and I can't figure out why the same Array returns different results a few lines later.

This is the code:

```
Population(int PopulationSize, ArrayList<Vessel> vessels) {
    this.PopulationSize = PopulationSize;
    solutions = new ArrayList(PopulationSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < PopulationSize; i++) {
            Solution s = new Solution(vessels);   
            solutions.add(s);
            System.out.println(i+" : "+solutions.get(i).getFitness());              
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < solutions.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(solutions.get(i).getFitness());

    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
0 : 4432.4956
1 : 2673.922
2 : 5166.998
3 : 4396.5454
4 : 5687.8555
5 : 2907.695
6 : 5005.9937
7 : 3289.161
8 : 3302.1948
9 : 5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
5193.338
```

**More source code.`**

Solution.java

```
package geneticalgorithm;

import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {

    ArrayList<Vessel> vessels;

    public Solution(ArrayList<Vessel> vessels) {
        this.vessels = new ArrayList<>(vessels);
        generateSolution();
    }

    public void generateSolution() {    
        do {
            for (Vessel vessel : vessels) {
                vessel.generateParams();
            }
        } while(!isValid());
    }

    /* Getters */
    public Vessel getIndividual(int index) {
        return vessels.get(index);
    }

    // Save individual
    public void saveIndividual(int index, Vessel v) {
        vessels.set(index, v);
    }

    public float getFitness() {
        float fitness = 0, BPCost = 0, CHDelay=0, CBDelay=0;

        for (Vessel v : vessels) {
            BPCost += v.DistancePenaltyCost*abs(v.X-v.LowestCostBerthing);
            CHDelay +=  v.TimePenaltyCost*(abs(2*(v.Y + v.HandlingTime - v.SailingTime))/2);
            CBDelay += v.BunkeringDelayCost*v.BunkeringNeeded*(abs(2*(v.BA+v.BunkeringProcessing-v.SailingTime))/2);
        }
        fitness = BPCost + CHDelay + CBDelay;
        return fitness;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        boolean XOverlaps, YOverlaps;

        for (Vessel vTemp : vessels) {
            for (Vessel v : vessels) {
                // Initialization 
                    XOverlaps = YOverlaps = false;

                // Checking for X overlaps
                if(v.X > vTemp.X && v.X < (vTemp.X + vTemp.Length))
                    XOverlaps = true;

                // Checking for Y overlaps
                if(v.Y >= vTemp.Y && v.Y <= (vTemp.Y + vTemp.HandlingTime))
                    YOverlaps = true;   

                // Breaking the loop
                if(XOverlaps && YOverlaps)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Vessel.java

```
package geneticalgorithm;

import java.util.Random;

public class Vessel {

    Float X,Y,BA;
    Byte Z;

    Float ETA;
    Float Length;
    Float LowestCostBerthing;
    Float HandlingTime;
    Float SailingTime;
    Float DistancePenaltyCost;
    Float TimePenaltyCost;
    Float BunkeringDelayCost;
    Byte BunkeringNeeded;
    Float BunkeringProcessing;  

    void generateParams() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Float MinBerth = 0.0f, MaxBerth = LowestCostBerthing + Length;

        if(LowestCostBerthing - Length > 0)
            MinBerth = LowestCostBerthing - Length;

        if(MaxBerth > DataLoader.Quay)
            MaxBerth = DataLoader.Quay - Length;

        X = rand.nextFloat() * (MaxBerth - MinBerth) + MinBerth;
        Y = rand.nextFloat() * ((ETA+24) - (ETA+1)) + (ETA+1);

        if(BunkeringNeeded==1)
        {
            Z = (byte) Math.round(Math.random()); // 0 OR 1
            if(Z!=0) {
                BA = Y;
            } else if(Y - ETA < BunkeringProcessing) {
                BA = SailingTime;
            } else if(Y - ETA > BunkeringProcessing) {
                BA = ETA;
            }

        } else {
            Z = 0;
            BA = 0.0f;
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Presuming `vessels` is an object, you're putting the *same* object into different `Solution` instances.

Comment: You did not post the relevant code. Please post the `Solution` class. But by the behaviour, I would say you store the fitness in some static field. And please respect the Java naming conventions: fields (unless `static final`) should always start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Solution uses a static field. Make it non-static and each Solution will have it's own value.

Comment: These comments are insightful guesses, but they're just guesses. Please bolster this into a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  -- what we have so far isn't complete or verifiable. In making it *minimal* you might discover the problem. If so, be polite, supply the MVCE and the answer here.

Comment: The vessels object is the same but there's an element of randomness added in the constructor and stored in a few different fields. None of them is static.

Comment: "The vessels object is the same" the same as what? You showed us barely anything...

Comment: @PhoenixNoor then show the class definition. You create a new Solution each time, and after you do, calling getFintness changes. Try doing `Solution a = new Soluction(vessels); System.out.println(a.getFitness()); Solution b = new Solution(vessels); System.out.println(a.getFitness() + ", " + b.getFitness());` So either you have static field *or* you are keeping a reference to "vessels" and modifying that.

Comment: Just updated the post. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: You're modifying your vessels. Each of your solutions reference the same vessels. Then you modify them, so each Solution reflects the changes.

Comment: @matt is spot on as it looks. You give the same `Vessel`s to all your `Solution`s and you keep modifying those `Vessel`s. Therefore, the fitness at the end is the same for all `Solution`s.

Comment: This is now *verifiable* and *complete*, but next time please work on *minimal*.

Comment: I was suspecting it's working on the same reference, but how do we create copies of objects that are unrelated? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Trying to work on a genetic algorithm here and I can't figure out why the same Array returns different results a few lines later.

Each `Solution` is passed in a list of `Vessel` objects.  This list is used to create another list of `vessels` inside each `Solution` but it's important to note that the new list still contains the *original* `Vessel` objects.

```
this.vessels = new ArrayList<>(vessels);
```

This code doesn't create new `Vessel` objects – it just creates a new list of the same objects.  This means that even though you are creating a number of different `Solution`s, each one is dealing with the *same* `Vessel`s.  Whenever `generateSolution()` is called, it is calling `vessel.generateParams()` on the the same shared `Vessel`s and updating the values in the previous `Solution` objects.  That's why the value generated by the last `Solution` is the value printed out when you go back through the list.

I'm not sure what the intention is but if you are surprised by this then you probably want to add *new* `Vessel` objects to each of your solutions and not reuse the same list.

**Edit:**

In looking more at your `Vessel` object, you have some fields which really are constants:

```
Float Length;
Float LowestCostBerthing;
Float HandlingTime;
```

And you have some other fields which are calculations:

```
Float X,Y,BA;
Byte Z;
```

You really should consider separating the constants about the `Vessel` from the calculations generated by your solutions.  Also, as an aside, fields should start with lowercase letters, be primitives (`float`, `byte`) instead of objects most likely, and should be `final` if they are immutable.

One idea would be to have a `VesselCalculation` object which would hold the calculations and also have a `Vessel` field:

```
public class VesselCalculation {
    private final Vessel vessel;
    private float x, y, ba;
    private byte z;
```

So then the `Solution` would generate a list of `VesselCalculation` which would be modified.  The `Vessel` objects would be shared with the different 
`VesselCalculation` objects but would stay immutable.

```
private final List<VesselCalculation> vesselCalculations = new ArrayList<>();
public Solution(ArrayList<Vessel> vessels) {
    for (Vessel vessel : vessels) {
         vesselCalculations.add(new VesselCalculation(vessel));
    }
    generateSolution();
}
```

`generateSolution()` would then make changes only to the `VesselCalculation` objects that are local to this particular `Solution`.

Comment: Good spot, on the `Vessel`s themselves also being modified. I guess I'm so used to *not* modifying things like this, I skim-read the code assuming they wouldn't be.

Comment: Yeah mutability is so important @slim and we get tripped up when someone has a pattern like this that isn't.

Comment: The intention is to have separate unrelated copies, how do we achieve that? Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

`getFitness()` appears to use only values extracted from `vessels`.

Since every `Solution` contains the same instance of `vessels`, every solution will return the same response for `getFitness()`, given a particular state of `vessels`.

The constructor for `Solution` calls `generateSolution()` which modifies the contents of `vessels`. That's the reason your `getFitness()` result changes every time you create a new `Solution`.

I don't know the details of your desired algorithm, but it seems likely that each `Solution` should have its own copy of the list. It's up to you whether it should make that copy itself in its constructor, or whether whatever calls the constructor is responsible for creating that copy.

Because the `Vessel` objects themselves are mutable (and the mutability is used) you also need to copy them, rather than making another list containing references to the same ones.

In this kind of situation, using *immutable collections* and *immutable objects* can save you lots of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having the same problem, I was able to solve this by using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/715660/745426). The idea is to loop over the array and copy each and every element one by one while you're cloning them. Calling the clone() function over the ArrayList has no effect but cloning the ArrayList while keeping the same references.

You're going to have to implement the cloneable interface and to override the clone method while cloning each and every field manually.

Comment: See my answer @PheonixNoor.  A better solution would be to separate your constants from the calculation fields.