# Clone the complete ArrayList including containing objects into other ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, collections

Hi I want to copy one ArrayList to another. Able to crate new list but whenever doing change in the object of second list, it is reflecting to first list.

**Student POJO class:-**

```
public class Student {
private int serialNo;
private int rollNo;
private String Name;

public Student(int serialNo, int rollNo, String name) {
super();
this.serialNo = serialNo;
this.rollNo = rollNo;
Name = name;
}

public int getSerialNo() {
return serialNo;
}

public void setSerialNo(int serialNo) {
this.serialNo = serialNo;
}

public int getRollNo() {
return rollNo;
}

public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
this.rollNo = rollNo;
}

public String getName() {
return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
Name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student:: " 
+ "serialNo: " + serialNo 
+ ", serialNoDisplay:" + rollNo 
+ ", Name: " + Name;
}
}
```

**InSide Main Method:-**

```
    ArrayList<Student> arrayListOrignal = new ArrayList<Student>();

    arrayListOrignal.add(new Student(1, 100, "name1"));
    arrayListOrignal.add(new Student(2, 200, "name2"));

    System.out.println("******** arrayListOrignal **********");
    for (Student student : arrayListOrignal) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("**************************\n");

//METHOD 1

    ArrayList<Student> arrayListDuplicate = new ArrayList<Student>(arrayListOrignal);

    arrayListDuplicate.get(1).setRollNo(754);
    arrayListDuplicate.get(1).setName("name754");

    System.out.println("******** arrayListDuplicate **********");
    for (Student student : arrayListDuplicate) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("**************************\n");

    System.out.println("******** arrayListOrignal **********");
    for (Student student : arrayListOrignal) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("**************************\n");

//METHOD 2

    ArrayList<Student> arrayListDuplicate2 = (ArrayList<Student>) arrayListOrignal.clone();

    arrayListDuplicate2.get(1).setRollNo(754);;
    arrayListDuplicate2.get(1).setName("name754");

    System.out.println("******** arrayListDuplicate **********");
    for (Student student : arrayListDuplicate2) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("**************************\n");

    System.out.println("******** arrayListOrignal **********");
    for (Student student : arrayListOrignal) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("**************************\n");

//METHOD 3

    ArrayList<Student> arrayListDuplicate3 = new ArrayList<Student>();
    arrayListDuplicate3.addAll(arrayListOrignal);

    arrayListDuplicate3.get(1).setRollNo(754);
    arrayListDuplicate3.get(1).setName("name754");

    System.out.println("******** arrayListDuplicate **********");
    for (Student student : arrayListDuplicate3) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("**************************\n");

    System.out.println("******** arrayListOrignal **********");
    for (Student student : arrayListOrignal) {
        System.out.println(student.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("**************************\n");
```

**OUTPUT FOR ALL THE METHODS:-**

```
******** arrayListOrignal **********
Student:: serialNo: 1, serialNoDisplay:100, Name: name1
Student:: serialNo: 2, serialNoDisplay:200, Name: name2
**************************

******** arrayListDuplicate **********
Student:: serialNo: 1, serialNoDisplay:100, Name: name1
Student:: serialNo: 2, serialNoDisplay:754, Name: name754
**************************

******** arrayListOrignal **********
Student:: serialNo: 1, serialNoDisplay:100, Name: name1
Student:: serialNo: 2, serialNoDisplay:754, Name: name754
**************************
```

So I can see here, in all the tries(METHOD1, METHOD2, METHOD3) the Student object which is in arrayListOrignal get updated.

But I am updating only Student object which is in arrayListDuplicate.

So what is the best way to copy/clone ArrayList to other ArrayList and will not effect the fist ArrayList if we do any changes in the cloned ArrayList, even changes in side object of the cloned ArrayList.

***** Question Updated *****

Okkk...People are suggesting to go in this way [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents).

But in my case this is not possible to modify the Student class.

The above code is just an example.

Comment: Thanks buddy...but the problem is I can't modify the Student class.
Above code is just an example. Basically I am getting one ArrayList and want to clone. After that I am modifying the cloned ArrayList.

Comment: Try this


     ArrayList<Student> arrayListDuplicate3 = new ArrayList<Student>(arrayListOrignal.size());
    // arrayListDuplicate3.addAll(arrayListOrignal);

    // arrayListDuplicate3.get(1).setRollNo(754);
    // arrayListDuplicate3.get(1).setName("name754");

     for(Student s : arrayListOrignal) {
      arrayListDuplicate3.add(new Student(s.getSerialNo(), 756, "name756"));
     }