# Cast Exception when copying an ArrayList of another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

So I have an ArrayList of Products that I instantiate at the beginning of my Category class...

```
    private ListInterface<Product> products;

    public Category(String categoryName) {
           products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }
```

and I want to return a deep copy of all products of a specific category using the following method...

```
    public ListInterface<Product> getAllProducts() {
           ListInterface<Product> temp = new ArrayList<Product>();              
           for (Product prod : products.toArray()) // CAST EXCEPTION HERE
                temp.add(prod);
           return temp;
    }
```

and here is the toArray() method...

```
    public E[] toArray() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E[] result = (E[])new Object[size];

    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        result[index] = list[index];
    }

    return result;
    }
```

When running the program, I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.O
bject; cannot be cast to [L...Product;" in the 'for' loop of the getAllProducts() method.

I am confused as to why I am getting this exception as .toArray() should return a Product[]. Is there an easier way to deep copy and return this ArrayList?

Comment: What is a `ListInterface`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: The problem is the line `E[] result = (E[])new Object[size];`. You cannot cast arrays like this, any more than you can do `(String[]) new Object[] { "Hello", "world" }`. An `Object[]` is not a `Product[]`, even if the objects in the array are all `Product` instances, so the cast fails.

Comment: @azurefrog its an interface for the ADT list.

Comment: @kaya3 unfortunately that line of code is not mine (that's my professor's code). is there another way to copy the ArrayList without the toArray() method that is not overly complex?

Comment: @noob4lyfe The easiest way is just to iterate over the original list and clone() each element.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents

Comment: I suggest raising the issue with your professor, then. @azurefrog, this is a custom list class implementing a custom list interface; I suspect it does not implement `Iterable`, so that's not going to be possible.

Comment: @kaya3 Even if the interface doesn't support iteration, the OP's example toArray() method makes it look like direct access to the backing array (`list`) is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well,the `ArrayList` implements the `Cloneable` interface. So, one good thing you could do is start reading codes of the standard libs. I extracted this specific method:

```java
    /**
     * Returns a shallow copy of this <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance.  (The
     * elements themselves are not copied.)
     *
     * @return a clone of this <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance
     */
    public Object clone() {
        try {
            ArrayList<?> v = (ArrayList<?>) super.clone();
            v.elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
            v.modCount = 0;
            return v;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // this shouldn't happen, since we are Cloneable
            throw new InternalError(e);
        }
    }
```

I recommend you to always try to learn from it. And I hope it helps.