# How to deep copy a List<Object>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, object, clone

I have an object and this object also includes other objects, like this

Student :

```
    public class Student implements Cloneable {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public List<Integer> score;
    public Address address;

    ......

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

Address :

```
public class Address implements Serializable,Cloneable{
    public String type;
    public String value;

    ......

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

Now i have a `List\<Student> studentsList`  How can I deep copy studentsList？How can I copy studentsList if there are other objects in Address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement a correct `clone()` method like

```java
public class Student implements Cloneable {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public List<Integer> score;
    public Address address;

    ......

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Student std = new Student();
        std.id = this.id; // Immutable
        std.name = this.name; // Immutable
        std.score = this.score.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); // Integer is immutable
        std.address = (Adress) this.address.clone();
        return std;
    }
```

Comment: I just need to mention that `std.score = new ArrayList<Integer>(this.score);` is easier and more readable.

Comment: @Mohammed Deifallah : Your mention works only thanks to `Integer` being Immutable.
Let's imagine a `List<Adress>` your method doesn't work but mine will by adding `.map(a -> (Adress) a.clone)` in the stream.

Your method signature is a shallow copy and shouldn't be used in a deep copy context