# Using array.clone() and changing values, affects the original array too

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a program for an exercise that generates `numOfValidBoardsToCreate` Sudoku boards with `emptyCellsPerBoard` cells with 0s (fills the rest with random numbers) and then solves them. If a generated board isn't valid or solvable it tries to create another one until it gets it. Now let's say we request just **one** board with **75** empty cells and its solution for the sake of simplicity.

The `solve()` method checks if a board is solvable and if so it solves it and returns true. Now, since when i check for each board's validity in the if statement of the for loop using `isSolvableBoard()` which in turn calls `solve()`, i don't want to solve the original board since i'm going to need to display the original unsolved one and then the solution. So i decided to use `sudokuBoard.clone()` to make a copy of the original one and use that for the check and disregard it since it's going to be solved after the condition is evaluated. I'd expect that the original `sudokuBoard` inside the if() statement wouldn't be solved when i print it the first time but the output is the solved version. What am i missing here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BacktrackingAlgorithm solver = new BacktrackingAlgorithm();

        // Get the required input from the user
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of empty cells that the board should have:");
        int emptyCellsPerBoard = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter how many boards the app should create and solve:");
        int numOfValidBoardsToCreate = scanner.nextInt();

        // extra data to keep track of for printing purposes
        int numOfInvalidBoards = 0;
        int numOfUnsolvableBoards = 0;

        // finding the time before the operation is executed
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int[][] sudokuBoard;
        int[][] copyOfBoard;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= numOfValidBoardsToCreate; i++) {
            sudokuBoard = solver.generateSudokuBoard(emptyCellsPerBoard);

            // Create a copy of the board to pass to isSolvableBoard to test the condition without altering the board
            copyOfBoard = sudokuBoard.clone();

            if (solver.isSolvableBoard(copyOfBoard)) {
                System.out.println("Board #"+i);
                solver.printBoard(sudokuBoard);
                System.out.println("Solution of board #"+i);
                solver.solve(sudokuBoard);
                solver.printBoard(sudokuBoard);
            } else {
                numOfUnsolvableBoards++;
                numOfInvalidBoards++;
                i--; // run the loop again if we haven't reached the end
            }
        }

        // finding the time after the operation is executed
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //finding the time difference and converting it into seconds
        float sec = (end - start) / 1000F;

        // Print final message
        System.out.println("Empty Cells per board: " + emptyCellsPerBoard + "\nValid boards created: " + numOfValidBoardsToCreate + "\nInvalid boards created: "
                + numOfInvalidBoards + "\nUnsolvable boards created: " + numOfUnsolvableBoards + "\nElapsed time: " + sec + " seconds");
    }
}

boolean solve(int[][] board) {
    for (int row = BOARD_START_INDEX; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int column = BOARD_START_INDEX; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++) {
            if (board[row][column] == NO_VALUE) {
                for (int k = MIN_VALUE; k <= MAX_VALUE; k++) {
                    board[row][column] = k;
                    if (isValid(board, row, column) && solve(board)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    board[row][column] = NO_VALUE;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Checks if a Sudoku board is valid and solvable.
 *
 * @param board The given board
 * @return True if it is or false otherwise.
 */
boolean isSolvableBoard(int[][] board) {
    return isValidBoard(board) && solve(board);
}

/**
 * Checks if the given sudoku board is valid.
 *
 * @param brd The 9x9 board
 * @return True if it's valid or false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isValidBoard(int[][] brd) {
    for (int i = BOARD_START_INDEX; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = BOARD_START_INDEX; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
            try {
                if (!isValid(brd, i, j)) return false;
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { // if a given cell has a value > 9, an exception is thrown, so handle it
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Sebastian i looked into this but even iterating and adding each cell into the copyOfBoard array seems to not work

Comment: array.clone() is a shallow copy. Using any looping/streaming and copy the instances of the array will still just give shallow copies. Read this to see what are you options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents/63476622#63476622    . Of course there are always third party API out there, but java lang offers few options for deep copy.

Comment: @DigitShifter shouldn't Arrays.copyOf() perofrm a shadow copy? Or iterating over the cells and assigning the values to a new different array `int[][] newArr`?

Comment: I think I have tried it and only got shallow copies. Let me try and come back - 20 min.

Comment: yeah it looks like java when calling `clone()` on a 2D array, doesn't do a deep copy of sub arrays :(

Comment: I just tried Array.copyOf()  and it is confirmed it does only shallow copy also. You can try it yourself also. I tested it with the Dog class found in the first link I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents/63476622#63476622, and then used this main method to confirm. Coming up in next comment.

Comment: part 1 of main method:     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        dog1.setName("Buddy");
        dog1.setAge(1);

        Dog[] org = new Dog[] {dog1};
        Dog[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(org, 1);
        System.out.println("Before Test of deep copy:");
        System.out.println("org: " + org[0].getName());
        System.out.println("copy: " + copy[0].getName());

Comment: part 2:        System.out.println("After Test of deep copy:");
        org[0].setName("Cujo");
        System.out.println("copy: " + copy[0].getName());
        System.out.println("copy should NOT be change when changing array org. This is NOT a deep copy!!!");
    }

Comment: Put part1 and part2 together in your IDE and try it out, you will notice that the dog name is not deep copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a good solution is the following:

```
for(int j=0; j <9; j++) {
  copyOfBoard[j] = Arrays.copyOf(sudokuBoard[j], sudokuBoard.length); // deep copy of the subarray
}
```

Which basically performs a deep copy of each subarray of the 2D array.