# Creating objects in functions and passing them back to main, Java

Tags: list, function, return, new-operator

Hi kind of a noobish question, but I have a function that creates an ArrayList like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inversePrefList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I append to this list throughout the function and inversePrefList ends up getting passed to main. My question is, in main do I have to declare a new object again? like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inverseDoctorPrefList = 
            new ArrayList<>(createInversePreferenceList(problem.getDoctorPreference()));
```

or since the object already was allocated with 'new' in the function, should my line in main look like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inverseDoctorPrefList = 
        createInversePreferenceList(problem.getDoctorPreference());
```

thank you.

Comment: The best way to do things often depends on other things - like is the list that's returned used by other methods (and perhaps changed).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out and both ways would work.
The first way would end up creating a new arraylist which would be a copy of the one passed from the function.
the second way would not allocate new space, but it would use the same arraylist created/passed from the function. Thus both ways would work, but I recommend the second for code clarity and readability.

Comment: Yes, the constructor used in the first way is called a [copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083129/5959593). Not related but C also has this. You can verify that the first way creates a new `ArrayList` by doing `inverseDoctorPrefList1 == inverseDoctorPrefList2`, which should return `false`. And normally, no one uses the first method unless they have a reason to do so.