# Can pairs of element in an array converted and displayed in arraylist of arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to make pairs of elements in an array and store them in an `ArrayList` (`al` variable in below code). Then store those `ArrayList` objects in an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` (variable `finalList` in below code) and then print `finalList`.

I am able to get my output if I only use `ArrayList` and not `finalList`, but I want to know what is going wrong in my code. Why is it not displaying me the proper output?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    static int[] arr = {2,4,6,8,10};
    static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList> finalList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

    public static void makePairs() {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            al.clear();
            al.add(arr[i]);
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                al.add(arr[j]);
//                System.out.print(al);
                finalList.add(al);
                al.remove(1);
            }
//            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(finalList);
            finalList.clear();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        makePairs();
    }
}
```

This is the output I am getting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUK6p.png)

The output I am expecting is:

```
[[2,4], [2,6], [2,8], [2,10]]
[[4,6], [4,8], [4,10]]
[[6,8], [6,10]]
[[8,10]]
```

Please help me resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

You are adding the same `ArrayList` to `finalList`. I suggest that you verify this by running your code with the debugger of your IDE. You need to create a copy of `al` and add the copy to `finalList`.

There are many ways to make a copy. Refer to [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents). In the below code, I use the ["copy" constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) of class `java.util.ArrayList`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    static int[] arr = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void makePairs() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            al.clear();
            al.add(arr[i]);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                al.add(arr[j]);
//                System.out.print(al);
                finalList.add(new ArrayList<>(al)); // CHANGE HERE
                al.remove(1);
            }
//            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(finalList);
            finalList.clear();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        makePairs();
    }
}
```

Note that I only changed one line of the code in your question.

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
[[2, 4], [2, 6], [2, 8], [2, 10]]
[[4, 6], [4, 8], [4, 10]]
[[6, 8], [6, 10]]
[[8, 10]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir/mam. Many thanks to you for resolving my query. :)

Comment: @JavaBoi you can show your appreciation by accepting my answer or up-voting it (or both).

Answer (score 0):

i think because your "al" array is static, when you add it to "finalList" it still a static variable and still can be modified, so when you remove al(1), it will remove the element from the static "al" in the FinalList. In this case you can try add a clone of "al".

```
finalList.add((ArrayList)al.clone());
al.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir/mam. Many thanks to you for resolving my query.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when I was adding my ArrayList al to the 'ArrayList of ArrayList' that I created which I called finalList, it was not passing a new copy of al `ArrayList` but the reference to it.

I thought that it would pass a new copy as they say **Java is Pass By Value** but I see it's not the same case with arrays and `ArrayList`, we we pass them as arguments, there references are passed.

I found my solution by using the copy constructor of the `ArrayList` as suggested by @Abra.

Here is the updated source code.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    static int[] arr = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
    static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void makePairs() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            al.clear();
            al.add(arr[i]);

            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                al.add(arr[j]);
            
            /* 
            int[] array = al.stream().mapToInt(k -> k).toArray();
            
            ArrayList<Integer> newlist = (ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            finalList.add(newlist);
            */

                finalList.add(new ArrayList<>(al)); // CHANGE HERE

                al.remove(1);
            }

            System.out.println(finalList);
            finalList.clear();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        makePairs();
    }
}
```