# clone utility for HashMap in java

Tags: java

Is there java utility that does `clone()` method for `HashMap` such that it does copy of the map elements not just the map object (as the `clone()` in `HashMap` class)?

Comment: A side note: if your elements are immutable across the object graph - you don't need to clone them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about other objects referred to in the elements? How deep do you want your clone?

If your map elements don't have any deep references and/or everything is `Serializable`, you can serialize the map via `ObjectOutputStream` into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then deserialize it right away.

The only other alternative is to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know your key/value pair elements are cloneable:

```
HashMap<Foo, Bar> map1 = populateHashmap();
HashMap<Foo, Bar> map2 = new HashMap<Foo, Bar>();

Set<Entry<Foo, Bar>> set1 = map1.entrySet();
for (Entry<Foo, Bar> e : l)
    map2.put(e.getKey().clone(), e.getValue().clone());
```

Comment: @Oso: What happens if e.getKey() or e.getValue() is another HashMap() or other object that also requires a deep-copy clone?

Comment: well... this is a simple hashmap clone routine. I am actually assuming that the objects are cloneable, so the deepnes will be solved by the key/value objects themselves. In order to deepclone a hashmap without assuming serializable/cloneable, I think reflection would be a way (still not sure if true).

Answer (score 1):

The SO question **Deep clone utility recommendation** is similar to this one, and has [an answer that may be helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241100/266471).

To summarize, they recommend using [the Cloning library](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/) from Google Code. From personal experience, it deep-copies `HashMap`s.  It can even clone things that aren't `Cloneable`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the deepClone method at http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/netbeans-src/db/libsrc/org/netbeans/lib/ddl/impl/SpecificationFactory.java.shtml .  It is not generic, but it includes several built-in types (including HashMap itself, recursively), and can obviously be extended.

Answer (score 0):

Often copy should be deep. Here is an example how to "deep copy"

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

code:

```
public static Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> deepCopyMapIntList
        (Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> original) {

    Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> copy = new HashMap<>(original.size());

    for (int i : original.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = original.get(i);

        copy.put(i, (ArrayList<Integer>) list.clone());
    }
    return copy;
}
```