# clone Hashmap with reference to Object

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

i want to clone a `HashMap` which have a Object as value.
How does it works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998376/clone-utility-for-hashmap-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
public static <K, V extends MyObject> 
              HashMap<K, V> CloneHashMap (HashMap<K, V> input) {
    HashMap<K, V> output = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for(K key: input.keySet()) {
        output.put(key, (V)(input.get(key).clone()));           
    }
    return output;
}
```

where MyObject is a cloneable Object:

```
public class MyObject implements Cloneable {

    @Override
    public Object clone() {     
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {            
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you trying to clone the HashMap and all of its contents? Or do you simply want to create a copy of the Map?

If you simply want a copy of a Map you can use the copy constructor on HashMap.

```
HashMap copy = new HashMap(sourceMap);
```

This will create a second map with the **same** keys and value objects as the source map. If you want a deep clone, meaning you want new but equivalent objects you need to do something like what was suggested by @Tudor