# what are atoms variable and what are usage of it?

Tags: java

```
public List<Minterm> completeMinterm(Minterm minterm, String variables){
  List<Minterm> minterms=new ArrayList<Minterm>();

    Minterm m1=new Minterm();
    Minterm m2=new Minterm();
    for (int k = 0; k < minterms.size(); k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < variables.length(); i++) {
       ..
        }
            m1= minterms.get(k);
            m1.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),false));
            m2 = minterms.get(k);
            m2.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),true));

        ..
    }
    }
```

I used eclipse debugger to find errors, I don't understand, why the atom added to `m2` is added to `m1` too in the same time, when this line is run:

> m2.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),true));

any Idea why?

Comment: Because both `m1` and `m2` point to the object `minterms.get(k)`

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve... What's your goal?

Comment: I would like to assign minterms.get(k) to m1 and m2 and handle m1 and m2 undependly from each other

Comment: In this case you can use deep copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After this

```
m1= minterms.get(k);
m1.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),false));
m2 = minterms.get(k);
m2.addAtom(new Atom(variables.charAt(i),true));
```

m1 and m2 points to the same object (returned from `minterms.get(k);`). You can try to compare m1 and m2 hash codes or pointers (`m1==m2`), for example.

Comment: how can I assign minterms.get(k) to m1 and m2, sothat I can handle m1 undependly from m2 or minterms.get(k)?

Comment: I've already added comment to your question which says that you can use deep copy algorithms ro reach needed behaviour.

Comment: @AhmedSalah For further information on deep copies visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001026/java-deep-copy-library

Comment: Isn't there an elegant way to solve this problem, for example throw temp varaible?

Comment: @AhmedSalah You cannot just use a temp variable, since changing the temp variable also changes the original variable.