# Copy constructor v. implementing Cloneable interface

Tags: java, copy-constructor, deep-copy, cloneable

In terms of "best practices", which methodology is preferred for creating a "deep copy" of an object?

Comment: Use some cloning library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1241100/738746

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a copy constructor. `Cloneable` is a straight-up API disaster. See [*Effective Java* Item 10](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) ([Item 11 in the 2nd. ed.](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA54&ots=yYEkIgw5V_&dq=effective%20java%20cloneable&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

> #### Item 11: Override `clone` judiciously
>
> The `Cloneable` interface was intended as a *mixin interface* (item 18) for objects to advertise that they permit cloning. Unfortunately, it fails to serve this purpose. Its primary flaw is that it lacks a `clone` method, and `Object`'s `clone` method is protected. You cannot, without resorting to *reflection* (Item 53), invoke the `clone` method on an object merely because it implements `Cloneable`. Even a reflective invocation may fail, as there is no guarantee that the object has an accessible `clone` method.

Comment: +1 (for the link, mostly) What about other alternatives to Cloneable, though? (A copy constructor generally requires a known concrete type, which while often is perfectly fine, is different from Cloneable.)

Comment: This quote also seems relevant to this question: " In effect, the clone method functions as another constructor;
you must ensure that it does no harm to the original object and that it properly establishes invariants on the clone"

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the general idea of a cloneable interface. It is easier than copy constructor for API users .

The problems with Java's `Cloneable` and `Object.clone` are not that bad either; they can be overcome with a little effort. And you can always have your own cloneable interface.

Java 8 could fix `Cloneable` by adding the `clone()` method with a default implementation

```
interface Cloneable
    public Object clone() default {  return Cloneables.defaultClone(this); }
```

not sure they have any plan to do so.

Comment: +1 for a great point about Java 8. Though I think an `UnsupportedOperationException` would be a safer default implementation for objects that haven't explicitly defined clone().....