# Copying cached Map<String , List> object into temporary Map<String , List> object

Tags: java, dictionary, ehcache

I am fetching a `Map<String , List>` object from ehcache. I don't want to update that `Map` object, rather I want to copy content of cached `Map` into a temporary `Map`. How can I create a copy of a `Map` so that changing the value in the main `Map` won't also change the value in the copy.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you want to do. If you just need a shallow copy, the answer of Paul would suffice, or do the following

```
Map<String, Object> fromEhcache = ...
Map<String, Object> copy = new HashMap<String, Object>(fromEhcache);
```

However, if you need a deep copy, i.e. you need all the objects from the map to be copied aswell, you will have to iterate over the whole map, and copy each Object individually. Plus, the Objects in the Map will have to support some sort of copy constructor.

Comment: +1 Good to mention deep copy - the OP should really clarify what "changing value in temporary map" means.

Comment: +1 Please read this discussion if you want to deep clone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665860/deep-clone-utility-recomendation

Answer (score 1):

You could created a new `Map` instance and then call [`putAll(Map)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29), passing in the original `Map`. This will copy all the key-value mappings into the new instance.

If you're using Guava, you could also call [`Maps.newHashMap(Map)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#newHashMap%28java.util.Map%29) etc. to achieve the same effect in one line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... 
I already used passing map in constructor and put all n even clone . But when I am iterating List object from map and changing the object from list it still changing the cached Map object.
Can any one suggest are we have any util method like BeanUtils copyProperties which will copy map values to another map without any link.