# Cache.get() returns deep copy of element?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I'm using ehcache to cache a java pojo which has a plain  java hashmap as property.

Do i need to worry about concurrency modification exceptions in the following case?

```
thread 1:
- obj1 = cache.get(keyx)
- obj1.hashmap.put(x, y)
- cache.put(keyx, obj1)

thread 2:
- obj1 =cache.get(keyx)
- for(akey: obj1.hashmap.keys){}
```

I would suspect i do need to use thread safe implementation for hashmap and in addition make my pojo's thread safe?

Or does cache.get() gives me a "deep copy" of the element in cache and can i just do anything with the element key and value without worrying about concurrency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I did analyze the objects in the cache with the help of System.identityHashCode(), it seems that is depends on the situation.

Also interesting:
[Copying cached Map<String , List> object into temporary Map<String , List> object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121975/copying-cached-mapstring-list-object-into-temporary-mapstring-list-objec)

Comment: can you clarify this, how does it depend on the situation? I'd think it would return the same object and not a copy...

Comment: It depends, if the object has been serialized to diskstore and removed from memorystore then it will not be the same object instance. That is why i said "it depends".

Comment: Yes, in the case of diskstore. However, i guess if it is in memory store, it will be the same object, or?

Comment: If it is a memory store i would indeed think it would be the same object, but i'm not sure, just do a bit of testing with System.identityHashCode() and see if the same object is returned every time in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
ehcache has the properties :copyOnWrite and copyOnRead.
for example:

<cache name="properties"
       maxBytesLocalHeap="100M"  
        eternal="false"   
        overflowToDisk="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        copyOnRead="true"
        copyOnWrite="true">
</cache>

in the ehcache.xml or look at net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration#copyOnRead.
```

Comment: For ehcahe 3.x you need to configure copiers / serializers as mentioned here - https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/serializers-copiers.html