# Adding *copies* of entries from Java Map<String, Object> propertyMap

Tags: java, collections, immutability, defensive-programming

I would like to add *copies* of a propertyMap to my propertyMap:

```
  public void addProperties(Map<String, Object> propertyMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> propertyEntry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
      this.propertyMap.put(propertyEntry.getKey(), propertyEntry.getValue());
    }
  }
```

The code above does not do that but hopefully conveys the intent?

What's the best way to do this? I have done some reading on "cloning", "defensive copying", "immutable objects", Collections.unmodifiable... and the like but I am more confused than before.

All I need, in typical SO style, is a better way to write what I mean in the code snippet, please.

Comment: May I ask why you wish to copy this?  It may help us narrow down an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can just use [`putAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29):

```
public void addProperties(Map<String, Object> propertyMap) {
    this.propertyMap.putAll(propertyMap);
}
```

This is called "defensive copying". What happens here is the values in the local `propertyMap` are copied into the instance's `propertyMap`. A weakness here is that changes the given `propertyMap` aren't going to be reflected in the instance's `propertyMap`. This is essentially creating a *snapshot* of the given map and copying that snapshot to the instance field map.

There are other ways of creating defensive copies as well, including `clone()` and the `HashMap(Map)` constructor.

For immutable collections, the unmodifiable methods in `Collections` will return collections that throw exceptions when you try to add to them. For example,

```
Set<String> strs = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>());
strs.add("Error"); // This line throws an exception
```

Immutable collections protect their values by disallowing modification (removing and adding) while defensive copies protect their values by not referencing the copied collection (in other words, changes in the original collection aren't shown in the copy).

Comment: Doesn't that do exactly the same thing as the OP's own snippet? I don't understand what exactly the OP wants, but since (s)he has already rejected his/her own snippet as not doing what (s)he wants, I guess this one won't work, either.

Comment: The OP trying to add copies (clones) of everything in the map.

Comment: From what I understand, he wants a defensive copy of the given map. If that's what he wants (as opposed to an unmodifiable map backed by the given map) then this answer is correct.

Comment: Could you perhaps include information on what a defensive copy is (briefly) and why your solution fits the bill?

Comment: Thank you.  That cleared it up for me, and I'm sure it will for other viewers in the future.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I think for each key you don't have to worry about making copies because they are immutable. But for the values it depends on what type objects they are. If they are mutable objects then you have to make copies of all of them.

```
public void addProperties(Map<String, Object> propertyMap) { 
    Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> propertyEntry : propertyMap.entrySet()) { 
        this.propertyMap.put(propertyEntry.getKey(), cloner.deepClone(propertyEntry.getValue())); 
    } 
}
```

You can check this for deep clonning [Deep clone utility recomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665860/deep-clone-utility-recomendation).

From the homepage http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

> IMPORTANT : deep cloning of Java classes might mean thousands of objects are cloned! Also cloning of files and streams might make the JVM crash. Enable dumping of cloned classes to stdout during development is highly recommended in order to view what is cloned.

So, it's good to know what you are trying to clone.