# Deep cloning specific values from an Object Java

Tags: java, clone

In my java project I have two classes `Atom` and `SExpression` that I need to be able to clone. These both implement `Expression`. My `Atom` class only contains a `String` which I believe is immutable and therefore the class can be cloned safely with the following due to `String` no being able to be modified.

```
@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}
```

However, the `SExpression` class is more complicated as it has 3 fields: SExpression parent, SExpression next and Expression data. So that the expr.data.parent would be the same instance as expr.

```
@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    SExpression clonedExpr = (SExpression) super.clone();
    if(clonedExpr.next != null)
        clonedExpr.next = (SExpression) clonedExpr.next.clone();
    if(clonedExpr.data != null)
        clonedExpr.data = (Expression) clonedExpr.data.clone();
    return clonedExpr;
}
```

However, as you can probably imagine the parent field still refers to the old parent. Does anyone have a solution for this? The only thing I can think of is possibly having a class variable the `SExpression` of the current parent which sets itself to this each time data is cloned which seems like a huge hack.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to clone those objects? A much better approach would be to make Atom and SExpression immutable.

Comment: Some context might help, This is for a scheme interpreter so an SExpression is code. So say I have (Define x (some expression)) I have an SExpression linked with x. This is where I would want to create a copy so when it is retrieved the original still exists and the new one is a copy. I don't see how making it immutable would help?

Comment: There is no good reason to ever change an SExpression. If you never change it you don't need to make copies of it. Also using clone to copy an object is usually considered bad coding practice. Instead you have a copy method that creates a new instance with new.

Comment: Okay, but if they are all immutable then how would I do cdr as that involves changing the parent to point at the second element which wouldn't be allowed if it was immutable. This also applies to cons and car as well

Comment: cdr doesn't change the parent it returns the parent. cons creates a new cons cell - the building block of lists in scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you to clone entire Linked List rather than doing it for single Expression. 
Do it for where parent = null, next = null;

Answer (score 0):

This question may help you:

[Deep clone utility recomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665860/deep-clone-utility-recomendation)

Specifically the Cloning library recommended in one of the answers:

http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

I haven't played around with the library, but it looks like it may cover you.

Comment: I've looked at a few deep clone tools, but won't a deep clone create a copy of all the object including the parent field? Whereas I feel I need a partial deep copy and some references updated