# Why Collections.copy still copies Reference, it doesn't clone the Objects that are copied?

Tags: java

Ok, I just want to copy `List<String[]> list` to `List<String[]> list2`. After that I will modify the object in `list2` & I want that it won't affect any object int `list`.

```
            String[] s={"1","2"};
            List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();
            list.add(s);
            List<String[]> list2=new ArrayList<String[]>(list);
            Collections.copy(list2,list);

            list2.get(0)[1]="3";

            for (String[] strings : list) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
            }
```

Out put: `[1, 3]`

Why we change things in `list2` & it affect `list1`? 
How to fix it?

Comment: The answer to your question in the post is in the title of your question. The solution is also in the title of the question: create a copy of each array in the collection.

Comment: i want they clone the Object as well

Comment: Collections.copy does a shallow copy, what you want is called a deep copy.

Comment: The fact that you want it to clone the objects won't change what Collections.copy() does. If you want a deep copy, implement the deep copy.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665860/deep-clone-utility-recomendation) on stackoverflow for a way to change that behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Collections.copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) does not perform a deep copy.

It simply copies elements from one collection to another. It is basically the same as the `ArrayList` constructor, so you do not need to call both.

The first element in both list still refers to the same object. Thus, when you run your code, you are modifying the array in both lists. You can iterate over all your elements, and use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) on each list item.

Something like this:

```
private List<String[]> deepCopy(List<String[]> list) {
    List<String[]> copy = new ArrayList<String[]>(list.size());
    for (String[] element : list) {
        copy.add(Arrays.<String> copyOf(element, element.length));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

**EDIT:** Java < 1.6 version:

```
private List<String[]> deepCopy(List<String[]> list) {
    List<String[]> copy = new ArrayList<String[]>(list.size());
    for (String[] element : list) {
        String[] elementCopy = new String[element.length];
        System.arraycopy(element, 0, elementCopy, 0, element.length);
        copy.add(elementCopy);
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: but u can't do with any Object List<T> deepCopy(List<T> list) won't work

Comment: i got error when running ur code: The method copyOf(String[], int) is undefined for the type Arrays

Comment: there no copyOf for String[] in my Jdk

Comment: There is one for any `T[]` since Java 1.6. Are you using an old JDK?

Comment: Well, you can use [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) then.

Comment: System.arraycopy(element, 0, elementCopy, 0, element.length); but it still show [1,3] result? why?

Comment: When I execute the code with `arraycopy`, I see `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is to copy the collection **and** clone all the objects it holds. In your case you only have lists of strings. The others already gave you good answers for that. Just as a note. In general it is not that easy, because there is no universal recipe for cloning objects. Because each object in the collection could have references to other objects itself. And those objects could have further references to more objects. So it depends on what you need.

- Do you just need to clone the objects in the collection, but not the objects those objects reference to? 
  This is called **"shallow copying"**.
- Or do you need to copy all the objects down the objects reference tree. This is called **"deep copying"**.
- Or you might have requirements for something in between. Meaning you only need to copy certain objects.

You see there is no golden bullet which solves everything. That's why it is not implemented in a generic collection class. In some cases cloning might not even be possible if you are dealing with open file handles or other system resources.

But what you can do is, have your classes implement the Cloneable interface. Within the clone() method you can call super.clone() which does already a shallow cloning for you. Everything beyond that needs to be implemented by yourself. Then you only need to call clone() for each object in you collection in order to create the cloned objects.

This is how to implement Cloneable:

```
class MyClass implements Cloneable {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private MyClass c;

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Calling clone() would give you a copy of your MyClass-object. That means *a* and *b* would be copies as well as the reference to object **c**. But only the reference, not the object c itself. If you need that, you need to do something like this:

```
    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        MyClass clone = (MyClass)super.clone();
        clone.c = (MyClass2)c.clone();
        return clone;
    }
```

Here is a more detailed explanation for shallow and deep copying and the Cloneable interface:

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-clone-shallow-copy-and-deep-copy/