# Copy a model object in java

Tags: java, serialization, pojo

What is the best way if I want to copy a model object in java. Because writing copy() function for a nested object in java becomes a lot of works. I just want to avoid that. As a shortcut I use this approach.

```
    public static <T> T copy(T model, Class<T> tClass) throws Exception {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(model);
        final T copy = objectMapper.readValue(bytes, tClass);
        return copy;
    }
```

And use it like this.

```
    final McTrack copy = copy(new McTrack(), McTrack.class);
```

I have made a Utility function copy() that takes a model object and returns a copy of that. First I serialize the entire object into json and then deserialize  it again to make a copy. But I am not sure it really efficient. Is there any better way to copy plain old java objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Dozer library: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

You can easily copy whole POJOs from one to another like this:

```
Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
DestinationObject destObject = mapper.map(sourceObject, DestinationObject.class);
```

What is really usufull you can configure your own mappings like this:

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>yourpackage.yourSourceClassName</class-a>
  <class-b>yourpackage.yourDestinationClassName</class-b>
    <field>
      <a>yourSourceFieldName</a>
      <b>yourDestinationFieldName</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Additionally you can use different Technics to copy object, use custom factories, special getters/setters and a lot useful things: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html

Answer (score 3):

you can use method:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(aValue, aLocal);
```

in  apache **commons-beanutils** jar

click here [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) visit apache  document

Comment: Does it copy nested object's properties too.

Comment: sorry I havn't test deep clone yet, you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()). There are some arguments against it but it's usable. Beware, this is a shallow clone. It depends on the class you are cloning, if a shallow clone will suffice.

See also here for deep clone recommendations: [Deep clone utility recomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665860/deep-clone-utility-recomendation)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the once mentioned above, you can also try [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/). No configuration is required. In cases where it is important, there are [3 matching strategies](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#matching-strategies) you can use.

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
OrderDTO orderDTO = modelMapper.map(order, OrderDTO.class);
```

This is a library I (and my team) used for a very big project and was very convenient. I attach the getting started page [here](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/) that explains things better.

Comment: it does not copy the object, order and orderDTO are seen same object.

Comment: Check if all fields names and types are the same, since matching strategy needs it. It is a well tested and widelly used library, so may be better to check on your side Halil. And is better in performance than the accepted

Comment: As @HalilİbrahimOymacı said, this does not copy object (at least not by default). I had to set **modelMapper.getConfiguration().setDeepCopyEnabled(true);** to make a real copy of source object.