# How to deep copy a hasher in Java

Tags: java, hash, guava

I would like to hash a large number of `int[]` in Java. My arrays contain paths from the root to nodes in a tree (nodes are numbered), thus they are very similar on the first values (as all paths come from the root).

I am using [Google Guava Hasher](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained), I add each value of my array to the hasher to get the hashCode :

```
HashFunction hashFunction = Hashing.murmur3_128();
Hasher hasher = hashFunction.newHasher();
for (int i: myArray) {
    hasher.putInt(i);
}
int hashCode = inthasher.hash().asInt();
```

I would like to avoid hashing the whole array again for every path and only hash the last values by adding the last values to a copy of my hasher. Like this :

```
anotherHasher = hasher.clone();
anotherHasher.putInt(someInt);
int hashCode = hasher.hash().asInt();
int anotherHashCode = anotherHasher.hash().asInt();
```

But the clone method doesn't exist for `Hasher`.

Does this kind of copy would save computation time? Is it possible to implement `Cloneable` with a wrapper containing a `Hasher` even if the later is not cloneable? If yes how? Is there another way?

**EDIT:** For the records, what takes times in hashing with Guava is not adding elements with `hasher.putInt(someInt)` but the hashing itself called at the end with `hasher.hash()`. So even deep copying was fast (which is not, see the answer by Tomasz Linkowski), my approach is not relevant and does not deserve to be studied further.

Comment: I think clone method will not be supported, because it is very difficult to decide whether an Array was modified or not.. or in fact, its state is not constant.

Comment: Why is it important to know if the Array was modified? If I cloned the Hasher I want it to be independant from the previous one, so why should I care if it is modified (or the Array it stems from)?

Comment: Or do you mean some kind of lock over the Hasher during copy is hard to implement?

Comment: best way to do it is override the .deepClone() and set your own parameteres on the cloning, as the classes go deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with help of a library that performs a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) of an object (here are some [deep copy library recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/665860/2032415)).

One such library is [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo), with which this can be achieved by:

1. Instantiating `Kryo` (note that creation of this object is quite expensive + it's *not* thread-safe):

   ```
   Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
   kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());
   ```
2. Calling `Kryo.copy(T)`:

   ```
   Hasher anotherHasher = kryo.copy(hasher)
   ```

However, note that this might *not* be faster than hashing twice because:

- Kryo's `StdInstantiatorStrategy` uses [Objenesis](http://objenesis.org/) to instantiate the `Hasher` implementations (and I don't know how fast it is);
- and the recommended `DefaultInstantiatorStrategy` cannot be used because `Hasher` implementations do not have a no-arg constructor (see Kryo's [readme about `InstantiatorStrategy`](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#instantiatorstrategy) for more details).

I'd recommend benchmarking this using [Java Microbenchmark Harness](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) (note various JMH plugins at the end of the linked page).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found a way around without deep copying, as you said this would not be the fastest solution.

Comment: @BaptisteMerliot Thanks for accepting but if you found a better solution, you might want to post it as an answer and accept it instead so that others can find the best solution to this question.

Comment: The solution was to change my global algorithm and not just this part, so it becomes off-topic for this question.