# Java: pass a clone as function parameter and not the reference

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
    Graph g = new Graph();

    doCoverOperation(g)
```

where in `doCoverOperation(g, subset)` I tend to do some operation with `g` but I do not want to have any changes on my `g`. Since I came to understand Java is a *pass by reference*, I know this is how it is supposed to work, but is there a way I can pass a clone on `doCoverOperation`? Like, I do some operation with `g` on `doCoverOperation` but my `g` above does not change?

Any ideas on this approach? Thank you further!

Comment: "Since I came to understand Java is a pass by reference" - no, references are passed by value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480. But if you want to create a clone, you'll need to write the code to clone the graph. That's sometimes hard, and sometimes easy, depending on the data structures involved.

Comment: "*Since I came to understand Java is a pass by reference...*" - [Java is pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), always. If you want this to happen automatic cloning, you most probably have to wait for [Project Valhalla's value types](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169).

Comment: Java is only pass by value, but since references are literally that, *references*, objects in Java have pass by reference semantics.  It's a subtle point but something to keep in mind.

Comment: Search internet for "Java deep clone library", you'll find several , you can start with stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665860/deep-clone-utility-recommendation

Comment: I'd urge you to think carefully, does the `doCoverOperation()` method really need to be mutating its input? In general, methods that mutate their input data structure are less maintainable and more error prone than ones that don't

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented the `Graph` class yourself, then your class can implement the `Cloneable` interface like this:

```java
public class Graph implements Cloneable {

    // Your methods and properties go here
    ...

    @Override
    public Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the clone method like this:

```
Graph g1=g.clone();
```