# Copy object into another

Tags: java

Is there a generic way to achieve copying an existing object into another?

Assume `MyObj` has an `id` and `name` fields.  Like this:

```
MyObj myObj_1 = new MyObj(1, "Name 1");
MyObj myObj_2 = new MyObj(2, "Name 2");
```

Instead of

```
myObj_2.setName(myObj_1.getName()) // etc for each field
```

do something as following:

```
myObj_2.copyFrom(myObj_1)
```

so that they are different instances, but have equal properties.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object

Comment: This [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java/9834683#9834683) will help you.

Answer (score 8):

The convention is to do this at construction time with a constructor that takes one parameter of its own type.

MyObj myObj_2 = new MyObj(myObj_1);

There is no Java convention to overwrite the existing properties of an object from another. This tends to go against the preference for immutable objects in Java (where properties are set at construction time unless there is a good reason not to).

Edit: regarding clone(), many engineers discourage this in modern Java because it has outdated syntax and other drawbacks. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Answer (score 7):

Use copy constructor:

```
public class YourObject {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public YourObject(YourObject other) {
     this.name = other.name;
     this.age = other.age;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Object.clone()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) & [interface Cloneable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

Comment: Although this is correct, Joshua Bloch warns against using clone in Effective Java. Better to create a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The clone()-method is for exactly this job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use introspection to automate the implementation of your clone routines, so you can be safe you do not forget to copy some fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `clone()` method is best suited for these requirements. Whenever the `clone()` method is called on an object, the JVM will actually create a new object and copy all the content of previous object into the newly created object. Before using the `clone()` method you have to implement the `Cloneable` interface and override the `clone()` method.

```
public class CloneExample implements Cloneable
{
    int id;
    String name;

    CloneExample(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CloneExample obj1 = new CloneExample(1,"Name_1");

        try {
            CloneExample obj2 = (CloneExample) obj1.clone();
            System.out.println(obj2.id);
            System.out.println(obj2.name);
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```