# how to deep copy object in java?

Tags: java, class, object, deep-copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)

Is it ok to do like this in java?

```
public class CacheTree {

    private Multimap<Integer, Integer> a;
    private Integer                    b;

        public void copy(CacheTree anotherObj) {
            this.a = anotherObj.getA();
            this.b = anotherObj.getB();
        }

       public Multimap<Integer, Integer> getA() {
            return a;
       }

       public Integer getB() {
            return b;
       }
}

public void main() {
     CacheTree x = new CacheTree();
     CacheTree y = new CacheTree();

     x.copy(y);      // Is it ok ?
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java

Answer (score 4):

That's not a **deep** copy—both objects still refer to the same map.

You need to explicitly create a new `MultiMap` instance and copy over the contents from the original instance.

Answer (score 2):

`x.a` will refer to the same `Multimap` as `y.a` - if you add/remove elements to one it'll be reflected in both.

```
this.a = new Multimap<Integer, Integer>();
this.a.addAll(anotherObj.getA())
```

That's a deep copy.

Comment: How about the Integer x.b? Does it refer to same y.b or not ?

Comment: Yes, but `Integer`s are immutable, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: So you mean if i make changes in x.b, this will not change y.b ?

Comment: @tsubasa: You can't make changes in `x.b`, you can only change `x.b` to another Integer object (and this will not affect the Integer object in `y.b`).

Comment: I think the second line should be `this.a.addAll(anotherObj.getA())` instead of `getB()`.

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work if object types in Multimap were mutable. E.g. Foo objects in Multimap<Integer, Foo> or Multimap<Foo, Integer> would need to be deep copied.

Answer (score 1):

See this article, gives a very good example with code in Page 2.
It also explains the concept of deep copying in java

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip76.html

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very useful article indeed.