# JSON Parsing - NullPointerException at third Level ListView

Tags: android, json

I am parsing `JSON` into `ArrayList`, but everytime getting NPE,

at com.example.parsingjson.HotelAdapter.getCount(HotelAdapter.java:26)

```
    return arrayList.size();
```

my `JSON` looks like this:

```
{
    "search": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "location": [
                {
                    "title": "New Delhi",
                    "hotel": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hotel 5 Star"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Hotel Premium"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Bangalore",
                    "hotel": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hotel Comfort"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "location": [
                {
                    "title": "California",
                    "hotel": [
                        {
                            "name": "Hotel Zone"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Actually I am successful of parsing first 2 Level of `JSON` but while trying to parse third level of `JSON` getting **NullPointerException**

and **Log** says:

```
06-21 16:28:52.310: D/AbsListView(9439): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-21 16:28:52.460: D/libEGL(9439): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-21 16:28:52.490: D/libEGL(9439): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-21 16:28:52.495: D/libEGL(9439): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-21 16:28:52.495: D/(9439): Device driver API match
06-21 16:28:52.495: D/(9439): Device driver API version: 10
06-21 16:28:52.495: D/(9439): User space API version: 10 
06-21 16:28:52.495: D/(9439): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Sep 25 15:06:14 KST 2012 
06-21 16:28:52.515: D/OpenGLRenderer(9439): Enabling debug mode 0
06-21 16:28:53.405: D/dalvikvm(9439): GC_CONCURRENT freed 190K, 10% free 12379K/13703K, paused 2ms+26ms, total 45ms
06-21 16:28:55.540: D/GestureDetector(9439): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-21 16:28:55.630: D/batchname::(9439): USA
06-21 16:28:55.735: D/AbsListView(9439): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-21 16:28:55.740: D/Location-fetchedname::(9439): USA
06-21 16:28:55.745: D/Location-checkdata:(9439): [com.example.parsingjson.Location@42780ab8]
06-21 16:28:55.865: E/SpannableStringBuilder(9439): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-21 16:28:55.865: E/SpannableStringBuilder(9439): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-21 16:28:57.470: D/GestureDetector(9439): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
06-21 16:28:57.570: D/dalvikvm(9439): GC_CONCURRENT freed 265K, 11% free 12543K/13959K, paused 5ms+4ms, total 30ms
06-21 16:28:57.805: D/AbsListView(9439): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-21 16:28:57.805: D/Hotel-fetchedname::(9439): California
06-21 16:28:57.810: D/Hotel-checkdata:(9439): null
06-21 16:28:57.820: D/AndroidRuntime(9439): Shutting down VM
06-21 16:28:57.820: W/dalvikvm(9439): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a052a0)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parsingjson/com.example.parsingjson.HotelActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at com.example.parsingjson.HotelAdapter.getCount(HotelAdapter.java:26)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at com.example.parsingjson.HotelActivity.onCreate(HotelActivity.java:42)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
06-21 16:28:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(9439):     ... 11 more
06-21 16:29:07.220: I/Process(9439): Sending signal. PID: 9439 SIG: 9
```

First Level: **CountryActivity.java**

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // url
            jsonobjectMaps = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("URL");
            try {

                arraylistSearch = new ArrayList<Search>();
                JSONArray jsonArrayBatches = jsonobjectMaps.getJSONArray("search");             
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayBatches.length(); i++) {                   
                    jsonobjectMaps = jsonArrayBatches.getJSONObject(i);
                    Search batches = new Search();
                    batches.setCountry(jsonobjectMaps.getString("country"));

                    arraylistStudent = new ArrayList<Location>();
                    JSONArray jsonArrayStudents = jsonobjectMaps.getJSONArray("location");
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayStudents.length(); j++) {
                        jsonobjectMaps = jsonArrayStudents.getJSONObject(j);
                        Location students = new Location();
                        students.setTitle(jsonobjectMaps.getString("title"));
                        arraylistStudent.add(students);

                        arraylistHotel = new ArrayList<Hotel>();
                        JSONArray jsonArrayHotel = jsonobjectMaps.getJSONArray("hotel");
                        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArrayHotel.length(); k++) {
                            jsonobjectMaps = jsonArrayHotel.getJSONObject(k);
                            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
                            hotel.setName(jsonobjectMaps.getString("name"));
                            arraylistHotel.add(hotel);
                        }
                    }       

                    arraylistSearch.add(batches);
                    batches.setLocation(arraylistStudent);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new CountryAdapter(CountryActivity.this, arraylistSearch);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Comment: show your HotelAdapter() class.

Comment: the error is in your HotelAdapter class show it.

Comment: placed HotelAdapter class code, check now

Comment: check whether you are getting data from bundle or not. `batches.getHotel()` whether this contain data or not.

Comment: what is `batches` in **HotelActivity.java**?

Comment: the Location class object, check my updated code above

Comment: does `Location.getHotel()` method returns `ArrayList<Hotel>` ?

Comment: getting null arrayListHotel = batches.getHotel();
  Log.d("Hotel-checkdata:", String.valueOf(batches.getHotel()));

Comment: Try debugging and check value of arraylistLocation (maybe null)

Comment: Why are you posting your LocationActivity? This will only be instantiated when the user clicks an item in the listview. And your error is before the user does that isn't it?

Comment: See my updated Log i hope now you will find some solution

Comment: you need to post `Location` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code segments what you have to at least understand the working of third level JSON parsing..

```
jsonobjectMaps = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/om6509fnyio3165/hotel.json");
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArraySeaches = jsonobjectMaps.getJSONArray("search");
                arraylist = new ArrayList<Search>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArraySeaches.length(); i++) {
                    Search search = new Search();
                    JSONObject jsonObjectSearch = jsonArraySeaches.getJSONObject(i);
                    search.setCountry(jsonObjectSearch.getString("country"));

                    arraylistLocation = new ArrayList<Location>();
                    JSONArray jsonArrayLocation = jsonObjectSearch.getJSONArray("location");

                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayLocation.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobjectLocation = jsonArrayLocation.getJSONObject(j);
                        Location location = new Location();
                        location.setTitle(jsonobjectLocation.getString("title"));

                        arraylistHotel= new ArrayList<Hotel>();
                        JSONArray jsonArrayHotel= jsonobjectLocation.getJSONArray("hotel");

                        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArrayHotel.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject jsonobjectHotel = jsonArrayHotel.getJSONObject(k);
                            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
                            hotel.setName(jsonobjectHotel.getString("name"));
                            arraylistHotel.add(hotel);
                        }
                        location.setHotels(arraylistHotel);
                        arraylistLocation.add(location);
                    }
                    search.setLocations(arraylistLocation);
                    arraylist.add(search);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here  is the Downloading JSON data and bind it to listview code.you can find it here.

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ArrayList<Location> arraylistLocation;
        private ArrayList<Hotel> arraylistHotel;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            jsonobjectMaps = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/om6509fnyio3165/hotel.json");
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArraySeaches = jsonobjectMaps.getJSONArray("search");
                arraylist = new ArrayList<Search>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArraySeaches.length(); i++) {
                    Search search = new Search();
                    JSONObject jsonObjectSearch = jsonArraySeaches.getJSONObject(i);
                    search.setCountry(jsonObjectSearch.getString("country"));

                    arraylistLocation = new ArrayList<Location>();
                    JSONArray jsonArrayLocation = jsonObjectSearch.getJSONArray("location");

                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayLocation.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobjectLocation = jsonArrayLocation.getJSONObject(j);
                        Location location = new Location();
                        location.setTitle(jsonobjectLocation.getString("title"));

                        arraylistHotel= new ArrayList<Hotel>();
                        JSONArray jsonArrayHotel= jsonobjectLocation.getJSONArray("hotel");

                        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArrayHotel.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject jsonobjectHotel = jsonArrayHotel.getJSONObject(k);
                            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
                            hotel.setName(jsonobjectHotel.getString("name"));
                            arraylistHotel.add(hotel);
                        }
                        location.setHotels(arraylistHotel);
                        arraylistLocation.add(location);
                    }
                    search.setLocations(arraylistLocation);
                    arraylist.add(search);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("data", arraylist);
                    bundle.putInt("index", position);
                    Intent sendtosecond = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondListActivity.class);
                    sendtosecond.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
                    startActivity(sendtosecond);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having same problem at two places. ArrayList objects cant be assigned directly. either you need to `clone()` or use **copy constructor**.

the error is in `HotelAdapter.java`

```
this.arrayList = arrayList;
```

you should do

```
this.arrayList = arrayList.clone();
arrayList.clear(); //clean up
```

and also do this inside `Location.java`

```
public void setHotel(ArrayList<Hotel> hotel) {
    this.hotel = hotel.clone();
    hotel.clean();
}
```

or you can use

```
this.hotel = new ArrayList<Hotel>(hotel);
```

your problem is because of [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441664/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-one-arraylist-into-another)

Comment: well.. that IS one problem.. and the another is when you are retrieving the bundle maybe.

Comment: check my comment above

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Duraiamuthan that WAS the solution to the OPs problem she just needed to implement it on one more place with the same problem :)

Comment: @Sonali was the answer helpful?